# What's the best way to raise an exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

I traditionally deploy a set of web pages which allow for manual validation of core application functionality. One example is LoggerTest.aspx which generates and logs a test exception. I've always chosen to raise a DivideByZeroException using an approach similar to the following code snippet:

```
try
{
   int zero = 0;
   int result = 100 / zero;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
   LogHelper.Error("TEST EXCEPTION", ex);
}
```

The code works just fine but I feel like there must be a more elegant solution.  Is there a best way to raise an exception in C#?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've marked GalacticCowboy's answer as correct as it is obviously the correct answer based on the way the question is phrased. Thanks again for the feedback and sorry if the question was vague.

Comment: For those thinking "there's got to be more to this question", you're right. In essence I was looking for a best way to raise/cause/simulate an exception. As James Curran stated, it's the occurrence of the exception rather than the throwing of an exception which I'm after. Forcing a DivideByZeroException is my default strategy though I thought there might be another way or maybe even a better exception to force.

More than likely there's no difference between throwing and "raising" an exception. The majority of answers seem to be of this opinion at least.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
try
{
  throw new DivideByZeroException();
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
  LogHelper.Error("TEST EXCEPTION", ex);
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat dangerous.  The CLR will behave differently when a user explicitly raises an exception that is typically raised by the CLR.  See this post for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/22/when-can-you-catch-a-stackoverflowexception.aspx

Comment: However, a divide by zero exception is inherently testable and throwable without *actually* trying to perform the division.  A stack overflow is a different beast, and is documented as such.  Other exceptions also note "not intended to be thrown by client code"-type annotations.

Comment: That is only for StackOverfloWExceptions. That is because many times, the catch clause would still be deep in the stack and overflow the stack itself. That exception can never be caught or handled when thrown by the CLR.

Comment: Or to restate a different way, just because the CLR *will* raise a certain exception doesn't mean I *shouldn't*.

Comment: @JaredPar Your comment convinced me that there's nothing sure in programming and I feel like living in ignorance recursion. When I learn something I think I know it, but nooo, not so fast, there's always some exception of the rule. I'm getting tired of waiting for a moment when I'll be sure to know something for sure :(

Comment: @kobac i have about the same feeling. Every time I have a discussion about threading I a) learn something and b) realize that previous code I wrote is in fact wrong.  It's disheartening at times.  The lack of surety in programming is part of the reason software is fragile

Answer (score 44):

Short answer:

```
throw new Exception("Test Exception");
```

You will need

```
using System;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Exception itself, you should either use an existing implementation or create your own. Exception is too generic.

Brad Abrams (of the .NET framework design team) states that he wishes they could redo that class with a private constructor to avoid its use like this

Comment: This is good for testing a new audit log.  Very basic that will break.  worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Logged in to vote for this. I am yet to see a good reason NOT to do it this way, especially for testing loggers.

Answer (score 5):

Build a custom exception for testing purposes ? Then you could add whatever custom properties you want the exception to carry with it on it's way through the exception handling / logging process...

```
 [Serializable]
 public class TestException: ApplicationException
 {
     public TestException(string Message, 
                  Exception innerException): base(Message,innerException) {}
     public TestException(string Message) : base(Message) {}
     public TestException() {}

     #region Serializeable Code
     public TestException(SerializationInfo info, 
           StreamingContext context): base(info, context) { }
     #endregion Serializeable Code
 }
```

in your class

```
 try
 {  
      throw new TestException();
 }
 catch( TestException eX)
 {  
    LogHelper.Error("TEST EXCEPTION", eX);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
        try
        {
            string a="asd";
            int s = Convert.ToInt32(a);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

It will return exception "Input string was not in a correct format. "

Comment: int s = Convert.ToInt32("asd");
You save one line.

Answer (score 3):

throw exceptionhere;

Isn't it?

Example I found was

```
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("A start-up parameter is required.");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

So, let me put in a pitch for continuing to do it the way you were.  You don't want to test what happens when a `DivideByZeroException` is thrown; you want to test what happens when a divide by zero actually occurs.

If you don't see the difference, consider: Are you really sure when you want to check for `NullRefernceException` and when for `ArgumentNullException` ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the feedback. I've marked GalacticCowboy's answer as correct as it is obviously the correct answer based on the way the question is phrased.

For those thinking "there's got to be more to this question", you're right. In essence I was looking for a best way to raise/cause/simulate an exception. As James Curran stated, it's the occurrence of the exception rather than the throwing of an exception which I'm after.  Forcing a DivideByZeroException is my default strategy though I thought there might be another way or maybe even a better exception to force.

More than likely there's no difference between throwing and "raising" an exception. The majority of answers seem to be of this opinion at least.

Thanks again for the feedback and sorry if the question was vague.

Answer (score 1):

`throw new DivideByZeroException("some message");` ?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just testing LogHelper's Error method, why even throw the exception? You just need a one-liner:

```
LogHelper.Error("TEST EXCEPTION", new Exception("This is a test exception"));
```

Comment: +1 from me, though the question was a bit more general than that - what is the preferred method for raising an exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomException: Exception
{
     public CustomException(string message)
        : base(message) { }

}
```

//
`if(something == anything)
{
   throw new CustomException(" custom text message");
}`

you can try this

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes you probably want to create a specific class (maybe TestFailedException?) and throw it rather than hijacking another exception type.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(condition);
```

give you an alternative?

Perhaps then use

```
catch (AssertionException) { }
```

to log a test failure.

See also [C# - What does the Assert() method do? Is it still useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163538/c-sharp-what-does-the-assert-method-do-is-it-still-useful) and http://en.csharp-online.net/Assert.