# Assertions C# + When to use them

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, assertion

I have seen couple of posts regarding usage of Debug.Assert in C#.
But I still have one doubt, may be its repeated, but I need to ask.

Is there a strict rule that Debug.Assert should be used only for checking members of a class or used to check parameters to a public method?

Or Can i Use Debug.Assert where ever I want, and to check whichever condition?

Thanks
sandeep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it wherever you want. Just be aware that it's a **debug** check. So it's checked *only* at development time while you test it. If you need your program to actually change behaviour based on a condition, you still need additional `if`s.

Read the [coding guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx) over at Microsoft and try to use tools like the static code analysis or Visual Studio (formerly FxCop) and StyleCop to have an automated way of checking your code quality and common mistakes.

Comment: I am concerned about a case, where I have parameters to a method, if they end up being null, should I throw an exception in that case ? if its a public method or even in case of private method, indicating invalidoperation? I am doing Debug.Assert,but in reality should there be exception cases everywhere then?

Comment: @Sandepku You should throw exceptions (`ArgumentNullException`, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or `ArgumentException`) for invalid parameters, or use `Contract.Requires()`. Note that if you want to check other program state for release builds *and* debug builds, you can use `Trace.Assert()` (but don't use that for argument checking!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson if I really have exceptions thrown, then why do I need to use Debug.Assert ? I am ok if the program stops its execution, even if its debug mode.!

Comment: @Sandepku You should never use `Debug.Assert()` to check parameters, and you are right - if you are already using an `if` to check them and throw exceptions, you do *not* need `Debug.Assert()`.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a strict rule that Debug.Assert should be used only for checking members of a class or used to check parameters to a public method?

Do *not* use `Debug.Assert()` to check parameters to a public method. Parameters should be checked in both debug *and* release builds.

You should use an explicit `if` followed by thowing `ArgumentNullException`, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or `ArgumentException` for invalid parameters.

Alternatively, use [`Code Contracts`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) to express the parameter preconditions using [`Contract.Requires()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.requires.aspx).

For further reference, see this thread: [When should I use Debug.Assert()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129120/when-should-i-use-debug-assert)

Other than that, then you can use `Debug.Assert()` wherever you want, but be aware that it might take a little more setting up for Asp.Net: [Is it worth using Debug.Assert in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762299/is-it-worth-using-debug-assert-in-asp-net)

Also see here: http://gregbeech.com/blog/how-to-integrate-debug-assert-with-your-asp-net-web-application