# ASSERT vs. ATLASSERT vs. assert

Tags: c++, mfc, assert

I am refactoring some MFC code that is littered with `ASSERT` statements, and in preparation for a future Linux port I want to replace them with the standard `assert`.  Are there any significant differences between the two implementations that people know of that could bite me on the backside?

Similarly, I have also come across some code that uses `ATLASSERT` which I would also like to replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The MFC version just includes an easy to debug break point.

Answer (score 3):

Replace them with [your own assertion macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732/when-should-assertions-stay-in-production-code). That's how you get the most benefit out of it (logging, stack trace, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either using your own macro, or #define's for the linux compilation. There's no compelling reason to give up any extra helpfulness on the Windows side (eg: built-in breakpoint), and no compelling reason to change a lot of code when some simple compatibility #define's will suffice.