# integer downcasts that will fail at runtime

Tags: c

say I have

```
void funcfoo(uint8_t len);
......
size_t l = strlen(str);
funcfoo((uint8_t)l);
```

funcfoo has to take a uint8_t. This code compiles and runs fine, but what happens is strlen is > max val for uint8_t? Its silently breaks.

Is there a standard way to do a downcast that will error out at run time if it fails. Or a compiler extension, or even a well known way of doing it.

I know I could roll my own macro to do it.

Note that this is c

Comment: Sorry, C doesn't have any built-in checking like this. You need to write the checks explicitly, e.g. `if (l > UINT8_MAX) ...`

Comment: "Its silently breaks." Yeah, that's pretty much just how things go with C. If you're looking for more safety, this ain't the right language, I'm afraid

Comment: @pm100 "integer downcasts" did not fail nor break.  The cast is doing what it is designed to do.  What you want differs, so the original is not failing nor breaking.  You simply want a different functionality than what the cast provides.

Comment: "I know I could roll my own macro to do it." --> Consider posting it.  You may get good feedback on it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes I know it did what it was supposed to do. But my program failed to do hat I intended - maybe a better way of putting it. As a long time c coder coming back after a sojourn in rust (which takes the opposite approach - you have to ask it real nice not to break in these situations) I could not recall if there was any common recipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a macro to print something. (only unsigned numbers as signed will invoke undefined or implementation-defined behavior)

```
#define CASTTO(to, val)  (((to)(val) != (val)) ? (printf("!"), (to)(val)) : ((to)(val)))


int main(void)
{
    unsigned x;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {   
        x = rand() &0xfff;
        printf("%"PRIx8" (x = %x)\n", CASTTO(uint8_t, x), x);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sjq89M9Y6

Comment: Minor: `printf("!")` may not print right away.  A timely print would be more informative diagnostic-wise.  Consider `printf("!\n")` or a print to `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

I would think to do the following, although it is a bit cumbersome, using the [assert macro](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/%7Ejohnr/tutorials/assertions.html) would achieve your goal of throwing an error in runtime:

```
#include <assert.h>

void funcfoo(uint8_t len);
......
size_t l = strlen(str);

uint8_t l_downcast = (uint8_t)l;

assert(l == l_downcast);

funcfoo(l_downcast);
```

ETA: As per the comment by chux, the assert macro does not execute if not compiled in `DEBUG` mode. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389901/23068431) defines an `ASSERT` that runs even if `NDEBUG` is defined.
This being said, debugging is there for a reason, if your assertions don’t pass in Debug, a better solution may be to refactor `funcfoo` in a manner that removes the necessity of the downcast.

Comment: OP may want something stronger than `assert()`, something that always fails, even when not in `DEBUG` mode.