# what are the effects of inline?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, inline

I had a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645896/can-i-make-alias-to-singletone-function/3645900#3645900) with [Johannes Schaub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) regarding the keyword `inline`.
The code there was this:

```
namespace ... {
    static void someFunction() {
        MYCLASS::GetInstance()->someFunction();
    }
};
```

He stated that:

> Putting this as an inline function may
> save code size in the executable

But according to my findings [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function#Language_support) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx) it wouldn't be needed, since:

- *[Inline] only occurs if the compiler's cost/benefit analysis show it to be profitable*
- *Mainstream C++ compilers like Microsoft Visual C++ and GCC support an option that lets the compilers automatically inline any suitable function, even those not marked as inline functions.*

Johannes states that there are other benefits of explicitly specifying it, which I do not understand. For instance, he stated that

> *[..] "inline" allows you to define the function multiple times in the program.*

.. which I am having a hard time understanding (and finding references to).

So

1. Is `inline` just a recommendation for the compiler?
2. Should it be explicitly stated when you have a small function (I guess 1-4 instructions?)
3. What other effects are there when writing `inline`?
4. is it needed to state `inline` in order to reduce the executable file size, even though the compiler should find such functions itself?

Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: FYI inlining usually *increases* executable size since the code is copied every time it is inlined. The hoped for gain is faster execution, not reduced file size.

Comment: What I said was in comparison to "static". Please read that comment thread and that static function before answering: If you put a static function into a header and use it in a way that can't make use of inlining, and if you put a non-static function marked "inline" into the header and use it in a way that can't make use of inlining, then the inline version will take less space in the final program because the Standard requires that *the function has the same address everywhere* , so in the final program, there is only a single copy of the code, as opposed to the "static" version.

Comment: @John: But inlining also allows the optimizer to "see" more code at once, giving it more to chew one. More often than never this actually results in _smaller_ code. This is especially true for template-meta programming, where inlining will often eliminate (compile-time) recursive functions calls.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub : The standard merely requires that taking the address of a function twice results in equivalent values, not that there is a single copy of the code. In fact, the whole point of inlining is to have multiple copies of the code embedded in other functions (and thus taking codespace)

Comment: @MSalters I have a hard time imaging such an implementation, because it would actually duplicate fully identical code. This is different from C99's semantics, where inline definitions and external definitions of functions can do have different behavior, but still need to have the same address. So C99 falls back to the external definition when taking address, and possibly uses the inline definition otherwise (but doesn't necessarily inline the call). Such things don't exist in C++ though. There is only one behavior for an inline function here. Note that i assumed that calls are *not* inlined.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: I understand that there are (older) implementations which did this, unintentionally. The non-inlined functions ended up in multiple object files, and the linker simply failed to eliminate identical copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is inline just a recommendation for the compiler?

Yes.

> **7.1.2 Function specifiers**
>
> **2** A function declaration (8.3.5, 9.3, 11.4) with an inline specifier declares an inline function. The inline
>   specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call
>   is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism. An implementation is not required to perform this
>   inline substitution at the point of call; however, even if this inline substitution is omitted, the other rules
>   for inline functions defined by 7.1.2 shall still be respected.

For example from MSDN:

> The compiler treats the inline expansion options and keywords as suggestions. There is no guarantee that functions will be inlined. You cannot force the compiler to inline a particular function, even with the __forceinline keyword. When compiling with /clr, the compiler will not inline a function if there are security attributes applied to the function.

Note though:

> **3.2 One definition rule**
>
> **3** [...]An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is used.
>
> **4** An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is used and shall have exactly
>   the same definition in every case (3.2). [ Note: a call to the inline function may be encountered before its
>   definition appears in the translation unit. —end note ] If the definition of a function appears in a translation
>   unit before its first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed. ***If a function with external linkage is
>   declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears;
>   no diagnostic is required.*** An inline function with external linkage shall have the same address in all
>   translation units. A static local variable in an extern inline function always refers to the same object.
>   A string literal in the body of an extern inline function is the same object in different translation units.
>   [ Note: A string literal appearing in a default argument expression is not in the body of an inline function
>   merely because the expression is used in a function call from that inline function. —end note ] A type
>   defined within the body of an extern inline function is the same type in every translation unit.

[Note: Emphasis mine]

A TU is basically a set of headers plus an implementation file (`.cpp`) which leads to an object file.

> Should it be explicitly stated when you have a small function (I
>   guess 1-4 instructions?)

Absolutely. Why not help the compiler help you generate less code? Usually, if the prolog/epilog part incurs more cost than having it inline force the compiler to generate them? But you must, *absolutely must* go through this GOTW article before getting started with inlining: [**GotW #33: Inline**](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/033.htm)

> What other benefits are there with writing inline?

- `namespace`s can be `inline` too. Note that member functions defined in the class body itself are inline by default. So are implicitly generated special member functions.
- Function templates cannot be defined in an implementation file (see [FAQ 35.12](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12)) unless of course you provide a explicit instantiations (for all types for which the template is used -- generally a PITA IMO). See the DDJ article on [**Moving Templates Out of Header Files**](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403420) (If you are feeling weird read on this other article on the `export` keyword which was dropped from the standard.)

> Is it needed to state inline in order to reduce the executable file
>   size, even though the compiler
>   (according to wikipedia [I know, bad
>   reference]) should find such functions
>   itself?

Again, as I said, as a good programmer, you should, when you can, help the compiler. But [here's](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.3) what the C++ FAQ has to offer about `inline`. So be wary. Not all compilers do this sort of analysis so you should read the documentation on their optimization switches. E.g: GCC does something similar:

> You can also direct GCC to try to integrate all “simple enough” functions into their callers with the option -finline-functions.

Most compilers allow you to override the compiler's cost/benefit ratio analysis to some extent. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) documentation is worth reading.

Comment: where did you find the "7.1.2 Function specifiers" information? it states that the other rules are to be respected (but I don't know where to find it). Where good answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

To restate what I said in those little comment boxes. In particular, I was never talking about inlin-*ing*:

```
// foo.h:
static void f() {
  // code that can't be inlined
}

// TU1 calls f
// TU2 calls f
```

Now, both TU1 and TU2 have their own copy of `f` - the code of `f` is in the executable two times.

```
// foo.h:
inline void f() {
  // code that can't be inlined
}

// TU1 calls f
// TU2 calls f
```

Both TUs will emit specially marked versions of `f` that are effectively merged by the linker by discarding all but one of them. The code of `f` only exists one time in the executable.

**Thus we have saved space in the executable**.

Answer (score 3):

> Is inline just a recommendation for the compiler?

Yes. But the linker needs it if there are multiple definitions of the function (see below)

> Should it be explicitly stated when you have a small function (I guess 1-4 instructions?)

On functions that are defined in header files it is (usually) needed. It does not hurt to add it to small functions (but I don't bother). Note class members defined within the class declaration are automatically declared inline.

> What other benefits are there with writing inline?

It will stop linker errors if used correctly.

> is it needed to state inline in order to reduce the executable file size, even though the compiler (according to wikipedia [I know, bad reference]) should find such functions itself?

No. The compiler makes a cost/benefit comparison of inlining each function call and makes an appropriate choice. Thus calls to a function may be inlined in curtain situations and not inlined in other (depending on how the compilers algorithm works).

Speed/Space are two competing forces and it depends what the compiler is optimizing for which will determine weather functions are inlined and weather the executable will grow or shrink.

Also note if excessively aggressive inlining is used causing the program to expand too much, then locality of reference is lost and this can actually slow the program down (as more executable pages need to be brought into memory).

Multiple definition:

File: head.h

```
// Without inline the linker will choke.
/*inline*/       int  add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
extern void test()
```

File: main.cpp

```
#include "head.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << add(2,3) << std::endl;
    test();
}
```

File: test.cpp

```
#include "head.h"
#include <iostream>

void test()
{
    std::cout << add(2,3) << std::endl;
}
```

Here we have two definitions of add(). One in main.o and one in test.o

Comment: Keep in mind that inlining might actually reduce the execution speed if more code has to be kept in the cache.

Comment: But if you have `#pragma once` or `#ifndef #define`, it would work.. right..?

Comment: @Michael: That will not help as those are reset for each compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, inline function may increase executable size, because inline function code is duplicated in every place where this function is called. With modern C++ compilers, inline mostly allows to programmer to believe, that he writes high-performance code. Compiler decides itself whether to make function inline or not. So, writing inline just allows us to feel better...

Comment: @Martin York: The compiler's heuristics make a far better decision than the vast, vast majority of human programmers.

Comment: @DeadMG: Absolutely (never let a human do the job of the compiler). I was just trying to pointing out the absolute statement "inline function may increase executable size" is not accurate.

Comment: well, the argument falls when you know that the compiler silently dismisses it, right? :) However, Johannes stated that there actually IS a reason why it has to be written. I'm not sure why that was.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. It's nothing more.
2. No.
3. You hint the compiler that it's a function that gets called *a lot*, where the jump-to-the-function part takes a lot of the execution time.
   The compiler might decide to put the function code right where it gets called instead where normal functions are. However, if a function is inlined in x places, you need x times the space of a normal function.
4. Always trust your compiler to be much smarter than yourself on the subject of <strike>premature</strike> micro-optimization.

Comment: 4: spot on, hehe.. I understand these, this is the comprehension I had as well. But what then is Johannes trying to tell me? I know he's right, I can see it on the reputation he has :) But I just can't figure it out..

Comment: 4: add "... unless you are a compiler writer yourself".

Comment: @Lothar: How about: Unless it's your own compiler?

Comment: Unless my compiler outputs some C code which is feed to the C Compiler which i previously intensive tested about code generation by disassembling generated code :-)  And i have to say in general most people overestimate the cleverness of a compiler (Intel had to pay 100 billions in wasted EPIC Itanium investment to learn that).

Comment: Most programmers _mis_estimate the cleverness of a compiler. In some areas, humans beat compilers hands down, in others they've got no chance. Just like ordinary people are suprised that a computer is perfect in math, but can barely write understandable English.

Comment: @MSalters: Compilers can often beat humans in cases where the compilers and the humans *perceive the same requirements*.  The biggest places where humans beat compilers center around cases where programs have requirements that differ from those a compiler knows how to optimize, or--in many cases--requirements which are looser than anything which a language can specify.  If a function needs to return `x-y<z` in cases where `x-y` fits in the range of `int`, and arbitrarily yield zero or one otherwise, a human coding for that requirement could beat any compiler given strictly-conforming C.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to this:

> And "inline" allows you to define the function multiple times in the program.

I can think of one instance where this is useful: Making copy protection code harder to crack. If you have a program that takes user information and verifies it against a registration key, inlining the function that does the verification will make it harder for a cracker to find all duplicates of that function.

As to other points:

1. `inline` is just a recommendation to compiler, but there are `#pragma` directives that can force inlining of any function.
2. Since it's just a recommendation, it's probably safe to explicitly ask for it and let the compiler override your recommendation. But it's probably better to omit it altogether and let the compiler decide.
3. The obfuscation mentioned above is one possible benefit of inlining.
4. As others have mentioned, `inline` would actually increase the size of the compiled code.

Comment: _@ShaderOp_, I believe your argument for inlining copy protection functions is flawed. Even if such a function was inlined by the compiler, in how many different places will the function get called? Possibly not that many, perhaps even just from one place. (Unless you really validate the serial key provided by the user every time your program does something, and not just at the program's start.) Inlining or not inlining won't make a huge difference, then.

Comment: @stakx: I wasn't attempting to make a case for inining as an anti-cracking method. It's just one possible use case that I've seen suggested elsewhere as an added layer of obfuscation. See item "A" under the heading "Making it harder for crackers" in this article: http://www.brandonstaggs.com/2007/07/26/implementing-a-partial-serial-number-verification-system-in-delphi/

Comment: _@ShaderOp,_ from the article you linked to: _"[...] but also gives the cracker that many more places to examine [...]"_. That's exactly what I doubt. Inlining functions for this reason only makes sense when they're called from several different locations.

Comment: @stakx: I believe the author of the article advocates doing just that. In item "B" in the same article he suggests to *"sprinkle the real checks into various operations."*

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it will readily ignore it when it thinks the function is too large or uses incompatible features (exception handling perhaps).  Furthermore, there is usually a compiler setting to let it automatically inline functions that it deems worthy (/Ob2 in MSVC).
2. It should be explicitly stated if you put the definition of the function in the header file.  Which is usually necessary to ensure that multiple translation units can take advantage of it.  And to avoid multiple definition errors.  Furthermore, *inline* functions are put in the COMDAT section.  Which tells the linker that it can pick just one of the multiple definitions.  Equivalent to __declspec(selectany) in MSVC.
3. 
4. Inlined functions don't usually make the executable smaller.  Since the call opcode is typically smaller than the inlined machined code, except for very small property accessor style functions.  It depends but bigger is not an uncommon outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Another benefit of in-lining (note that actual inlining is sometimes orthogonal to use of the "inline" directive) occurs when a function uses reference parameters.  Passing two variables to a non-inline function to add its first operand to the second would require pushing the value of the first operand and the address of the second and then calling a function which would have to pop the first operand and address of the second, and then add the former value indirectly to the popped address.  If the function were expanded inline, the compiler could simply add one variable to the other directly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually inlining leads to bigger executables, not smaller ones.
It's to reduce one level of indirection, by pasting the function code.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html