# C inline functions and "undefined external" error

Tags: c, external, inline-functions

I'm trying to replace some macro subroutines with inline functions, so the compiler can optimize them, so the debugger can step into them, etc.  If I define them as normal functions it works:

```
void do_something(void)
{
  blah;
}

void main(void)
{
  do_something();
}
```

but if I define them as inline:

```
inline void do_something(void)
{
  blah;
}

void main(void)
{
  do_something();
}
```

it says "Error: Undefined external".  What does that mean?  Taking a stab in the dark, I tried

```
static inline void do_something(void)
{
  blah;
}

void main(void)
{
  do_something();
}
```

and no more errors.  The function definition and call to the function are in the same .c file.

Can someone explain why one works and the other doesn't?

(Second related question: Where do I put inline functions if I want to use them in more than one .c file?)

Comment: It's unclear where you're putting those definitions, and when you're getting those errors. Is some of that in headers? Are you forward declaring in a header and trying to use it from another compilation unit?

Comment: Oh, the function definitions and the call to the function are both in the same .c file.

Comment: Can you post a [sscce](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)? (Well, not compilable of course in this case.)

Comment: @Mat: Not sure what you're asking for.  I'm defining a function and then calling it inside the main function, which is in the same .c file.

Comment: I'm just trying to get you to edit your question so that it contains enough information to exactly reproduce your problem, so that it can be answered it correctly. Your question as it is doesn't contain the information in your comments. If you simply posted a complete C file that gives the error you're having, your question would be better. (But I believe some of the answers posted are correct already.)

Comment: In C, main() returns int. (except in Herb Schildt's books)

Comment: @wildplasser: Well the manufacturer's example code for this microcontroller is wrong, then.  Not sure where the return would end up, anyway.

Comment: It is a freestanding implementation?

Comment: @wildplasser: Not sure what that means, but probably.  It's an embedded microcontroller.  The main code never returns, and if it somehow did, there's nothing for it to return to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, the compiler does not always inline functions marked as `inline`; eg if you turn all optimizations off it will probably not inline them.

When you define an inline function

```
inline void do_something(void)
{
  blah
}
```

and use that function, even in the same file, the call to that function is resolved by the linker not the compiler, because it is implicitely "extern". But this definition alone does not provide an external definition of the function.

If you  include a declaration without `inline`

```
void do_something(void);
```

in a C file which can see the `inline`  definition, the compiler will provide an external definition of the function, and the error should go away.

The reason `static inline` works is that it makes the function visible only within that compilatioin unit, and so allows the compiler to resolve the call to the function (and optimize it) and emit the code for the function within that compilation unit.  The linker then doesn't have to resolve it, so there is no need for an external definition.

The best place to put inline function is in a header file, and declare them `static inline`. This removes any need for an external definition, so it resolves the linker problem. However, this causes the compiler to emit the code for the function in every compilation unit that uses it, so could result in code bloat.  But since the function is inline, it is probably small anyway, so this usually isn't a problem.

The other option is to *define* it as `extern inline` in the header, and in one C file provide and `extern` *declaration* without the `inline` modifier.

The gcc manual explains it thus:

> By declaring a function inline, you can direct GCC to make calls to
>   that function faster.  One way GCC can achieve this is to integrate
>   that function's code into the code for its callers.  This makes
>   execution faster by eliminating the function-call overhead; in
>   addition, if any of the actual argument values are constant, their
>   known values may permit simplifications at compile time so that not
>   all of the inline function's code needs to be included.  The effect on
>   code size is less predictable; object code may be larger or smaller
>   with function inlining, depending on the particular case.  You can
>   also direct GCC to try to integrate all "simple enough" functions into
>   their callers with the option `-finline-functions`.
>
> GCC implements three different semantics of declaring a function
>   inline.  One is available with `-std=gnu89` or `-fgnu89-inline` or
>   when `gnu_inline` attribute is present on all inline declarations,
>   another when `-std=c99`, `-std=c1x`, `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu1x`
>   (without `-fgnu89-inline`), and the third is used when compiling C++.
>
> To declare a function inline, use the `inline` keyword in its
>   declaration, like this:
>
> ```
>  static inline int
>  inc (int *a)
>  {
>    return (*a)++;
>  }
> ```
>
> If you are writing a header file to be included in ISO C90 programs,
>   write `__inline__` instead of `inline`.
>
> The three types of inlining behave similarly in two important cases:
>   when the `inline` keyword is used on a `static` function, like the
>   example above, and when a function is first declared without using the
>   `inline` keyword and then is defined with `inline`, like this:
>
> ```
>  extern int inc (int *a);
>  inline int
>  inc (int *a)
>  {
>    return (*a)++;
>  }
> ```
>
> In both of these common cases, the program behaves the same as if you
>   had not used the `inline` keyword, except for its speed.
>
> When a function is both inline and `static`, if all calls to the
>   function are integrated into the caller, and the function's address is
>   never used, then the function's own assembler code is never
>   referenced. In this case, GCC does not actually output assembler code
>   for the function, unless you specify the option
>   `-fkeep-inline-functions`. Some calls cannot be integrated for various
>   reasons (in particular, calls that precede the function's definition
>   cannot be integrated, and neither can recursive calls within the
>   definition).  If there is a nonintegrated call, then the function is
>   compiled to assembler code as usual.  The function must also be
>   compiled as usual if the program refers to its address, because that
>   can't be inlined.
>
> Note that certain usages in a function definition can make it
>   unsuitable for inline substitution.  Among these usages are: use of
>   varargs, use of alloca, use of variable sized data types , use of computed goto,
>   use of nonlocal goto, and nested functions.
>   Using `-Winline` will warn when a function marked `inline` could not
>   be substituted, and will give the reason for the failure.
>
> As required by ISO C++, GCC considers member functions defined within
>   the body of a class to be marked inline even if they are not
>   explicitly declared with the `inline` keyword.  You can override this
>   with `-fno-default-inline`.
>
> GCC does not inline any functions when not optimizing unless you
>   specify the `always_inline` attribute for the function, like this:
>
> ```
>  /* Prototype.  */
>  inline void foo (const char) __attribute__((always_inline));
> ```
>
> The remainder of this section is specific to GNU C90 inlining.
>
> When an inline function is not `static`, then the compiler must
>   assume that there may be calls from other source files; since a global
>   symbol can be defined only once in any program, the function must not
>   be defined in the other source files, so the calls therein cannot be
>   integrated.  Therefore, a non-`static` inline function is always
>   compiled on its own in the usual fashion.
>
> If you specify both `inline` and `extern` in the function definition,
>   then the definition is used only for inlining.  In no case is the
>   function compiled on its own, not even if you refer to its address
>   explicitly.  Such an address becomes an external reference, as if you
>   had only declared the function, and had not defined it.
>
> This combination of `inline` and `extern` has almost the effect of a
>   macro.  The way to use it is to put a function definition in a header
>   file with these keywords, and put another copy of the definition
>   (lacking `inline` and `extern`) in a library file.  The definition in
>   the header file will cause most calls to the function to be inlined.
>   If any uses of the function remain, they will refer to the single copy
>   in the library.

Comment: "First, the compiler does not always inline functions marked as inline" Yes, but isn't it better to let the compiler decide instead of forcing it with macros?  "this causes the compiler to emit the code for the function in every compilation unit that uses it"  But if it's unused in that file, it doesn't get compiled, does it?  There are compiled code size constraints here.

Comment: “Yes, but isn't it better to let the compiler decide instead of forcing it with macros?”  I don't understand this question. “But if it's unused in that file, it doesn't get compiled, does it?” It is compiled, but the machine code is not emitted; it is essentially “thrown away”.

Answer (score 1):

For `inline` functions to work with C99 (they only came there into the language) you'd have to give the definition in a header file

```
inline void do_something(void)
{
  blah
}
```

and in **one** compilation unit (aka .c) you place some sort of "instantiation"

```
void do_something(void);
```

without the `inline`.

Comment: Agreed. There seems to be a similar question here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597/is-inline-without-static-or-extern-ever-useful-in-c99

Answer (score 0):

You have to put them in a header file if you want to use them from multiple files.

And for the linker error: the default declaration of a function implies that it's "extern", but since it's inlined, the linker can find the compiler-generated symbol stub, hence the error.