# Compiling error when -std=gnu99 and inline function is used

Tags: c, gcc

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
inline int myfunc (int x) {
    return x+3;
}

int main () {

    printf("%d", myfunc(2));
    return 0;
}
```

does not compile when I use the `-std=gnu99` flag (I am compiling with gcc). This is the error it throws:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -std=gnu99 main.o -o main
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `myfunc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The compilation goes with no problems when `-std=gnu99` is omitted. Does anyone know why is the linker complaining if `-std=gnu99` is used?

Comment: Interesting. I tested with 4.4.3 and it gives me the same error.

Comment: I also discovered this when playing with `gnu99`, but it is standard C99 behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597/is-inline-without-static-or-extern-ever-useful-in-c99

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C99 you need to specify either a declaration to your inline function like

```
int myfunc(int);
```

or allow the compiler to actually inline the function by specifying `-finline-functions` or `-O3`.

Quoting the C99 standard:

> Any  function  with  internal linkage can be an inline function.   For
>   a  function  with  external  linkage,   the following restrictions
>   apply: If a function is declared with an inline function specifier,
>   then it shall also be  defined in  the  same  translation  unit.   If
>   all of the file scope declarations for a function in a  translation 
>   unit  include the  inline  function  specifier  without  extern,  then
>   the definition in that translation unit is an inline definition. An
>   inline definition does not provide an external definition for the
>   function, and does not forbid an external definition in  another
>   translation unit.  An inline definition provides an alternative to an
>   external definition, which a translator may  use  to  implement any
>   call to the function in the same translation unit.  **It is
>   unspecified whether a call  to  the function   uses   the  inline 
>   definition  or  the  external definition.**

So the compiler is free to use the external definition of `myfunc` - which doesn't exist if you don't provide it, hence the linker error. Why does it prefer to choose a non existing external definition? Because you disallowed inlining by not using `-finline-functions` or a optimization level which contains this flag.

Comment: I prefer thinking of inline functions as external functions with inlining capability enabled. probably it is a good idea to mark this functions as extern inline (at least in C99 mode): `extern inline void source1(void) __attribute__((always_inline));` in .h file and define in .c file as `extern inline void source1(void) {}` also consider either change flag `-std=gnu99` to `-std=gnu89` for example and remove `-fgnu89-inline` flag or rewrite code so it does not mess with compatibility modes introduced to old style of inline functions (both flag allows debugging inline functions - shadowing gcc)

Answer (score 6):

This is the `gnu_inline` hiccup.  Use `-std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline`.

For more information see [Function Attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (item `gnu_inline`).

The relevant passage:

> In C, if the function is neither extern nor static, then the function is compiled as a standalone function, as well as being inlined where possible.
>
> This is how GCC traditionally handled functions declared inline. Since ISO C99 specifies a different semantics for inline, this function attribute is provided as a transition measure and as a useful feature in its own right. This attribute is available in GCC 4.1.3 and later. It is available if either of the preprocessor macros **GNUC_GNU_INLINE** or **GNUC_STDC_INLINE** are defined. See An Inline Function is As Fast As a Macro.

Comment: Actually it's the C99 inline hiccup.

Answer (score 4):

You should declare 'myfunc' before define it.
For example this code can be compiled with -std=gnu99 option:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myfunc(int);

inline int myfunc (int x) {
    return x+3;
}

int main () {

    printf("%d", myfunc(2));
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATED**

Actually, regarding to the C standard inline keyword is just a suggestion to the C compiler. But compiler can choose not to inline. So it can do its own way, therefore.

In your example you can use function declaration as I showed above - or you can add **optimization flag '-O3'** (tested on linux gcc) and above - in this case your source code will compiled without extra-declaration.

**UPDATED**

Here you can find deeper explanation: https://blogs.oracle.com/dew/entry/c99_inline_function

Comment: but how will you explain compiling without declaration and `inline` ?

Comment: Interesting... I had before declared the function before its definition, but if you use `inline int myfunc(int);`, the same compilation error appears. Why should the inline be omitted here? Btw, I also got the code to compile by declaring `myfunc` to be `extern`.

Comment: This should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to specify that you are using and you want to adopt inline functions

> > ```
> > -fgnu89-inline
> > ```
> >
> > The option -fgnu89-inline tells GCC to use the traditional GNU semantics for "inline" functions when in C99 mode. This option is
> >     accepted and ignored by GCC versions 4.1.3 up to but not including
> >     4.3. In GCC versions 4.3 and later it changes the behavior of GCC in C99 mode. Using this option is roughly equivalent to adding the
> >     "gnu_inline" function attribute to all inline functions.
> >
> > The option -fno-gnu89-inline explicitly tells GCC to use the C99 semantics for "inline" when in C99 or gnu99 mode (i.e., it
> >     specifies the default behavior). This option was first supported in
> >     GCC 4.3. This option is not supported in C89 or gnu89 mode.
> >
> > The preprocessor macros `__GNUC_GNU_INLINE__` and `__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__` may be used to check which semantics are in
> >     effect for "inline" functions.
>
> Source: http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

So to compile your code you need at least this:

```
gcc source.c -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline
```