# Calling inline functions from file in C

Tags: c, inline

Basically, I have a FileA.c:

```
//FIleA.c
void inline something()
{  
 //short code here

}
void inline another()
{ 
  //short code here
}
```

Now I want to call these inline functions in another file main.c  **without** using a header file.
How should I declare the prototypes of these functions in main.c?

```
//main.c
#include "FileA.c"
void something(); 
void another();
// or ???

int main()
{
 something();
 another();
 something();
 another();

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you want them to be inlined in the other file? Or just called externally?

Comment: I want them to be inlined in the file I called them.

Comment: Then the function definitions belong in your header file.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but is there any way to avoid using header file since the functions will be only called in one file.

Comment: Inline functions always belong either in a shared header file, or if they're only used in one source file, in that source file.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6312597/1366431) actually suggests that there's no possible use case for defining `inline` functions in another .c file in this way.

On the other hand, if you `#include "FileA.c"` in your main file anyway, then you don't need to do anything, because you *are* using a header file (ending the name of an included file with `.c` doesn't change what it fundamentally is, it just confuses people reading your code).

Comment: If I remove my prototypes in main.c. It won't compile. (XCode, Linker error)

Comment: As a practical note, if you're using Xcode, the compiler will ignore your `inline` declarations anyway. Firstly because it knows better than you when to inline functions, and secondly because LLVM can inline functions at link-time and doesn't need to use this old-fashioned mechanism at all. Use the functions normally and they will be inlined if it's appropriate.