# undefined reference when calling inline function

Tags: c, function, undefined, inline, header-files

I am getting a really odd error from GCC 4.8.1 with inline functions.

I have two near-identical inline functions defined in header files (`debug.h` and `error.h`) in `src/include/`, with the only difference being what they print - one prefixes `DEBUG:` to the message, and the other `%s: error: %s` (program name, error message). When defining the functions both inline, and compiling a debug build (so it sets the macro `DEBUG=1`), I get lots of undefined reference errors:

```
src/main_debug.o
  gcc -osrc/main_debug.o src/main.c -c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu11 -march=native -Og -g -DCC="\"gcc\"" -DCFLAGS="\"-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu11 -march=native -Og -g\"" -DDEBUG=1 -DBTCWATCH_VERSION="\"0.0.1\""

src/lib/btcapi_debug.o
  gcc -osrc/lib/btcapi_debug.o src/lib/btcapi.c -c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu11 -march=native -Og -g -DCC="\"gcc\"" -DCFLAGS="\"-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu11 -march=native -Og -g\"" -DDEBUG=1

src/lib/libbtcapi_debug.a
  ar rc src/lib/libbtcapi_debug.a src/lib/btcapi_debug.o
  ranlib src/lib/libbtcapi_debug.a

src/lib/cmdlineutils_debug.o
  gcc -o src/lib/cmdlineutils_debug.o src/lib/cmdlineutils.c -c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu11 -march=native -Og -g -DCC="\"gcc\"" -DCFLAGS="\"-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu11 -march=native -Og -g\"" -DDEBUG=1

src/lib/libcmdlineutils_debug.a
  ar rc src/lib/libcmdlineutils_debug.a src/lib/cmdlineutils_debug.o
  ranlib src/lib/libcmdlineutils_debug.a

debug
  gcc -obtcwatch-debug src/main_debug.o -Lsrc/lib/ -lbtcapi_debug -lcmdlineutils_debug -lcurl  -ljansson 
src/main_debug.o: In function `main':
/home/marcoms/btcwatch/src/main.c:148: undefined reference to `debug'
src/main_debug.o:/home/marcoms/btcwatch/src/main.c:185: more undefined references to `debug' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [debug] Error 1
```

But changing `debug()`'s definition to `static inline` removes the errors. But I have never received any errors from `error()`'s definition, although its defenition is `inline`, and not `static inline`.

The definitions are all in headers (i.e. not prototyped)

Comment: I have found that the compiler will result in `undefined reference` on referenceing the `inline func();` with `-O0` or absent `-O` flag, and will compile successfully with `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`.

Comment: @exebook Thanks, that solved my problem. An explanation is provided in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245521/c99-inline-function-in-c-file.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html#Inline), passing `-std=gnu11` enables C99 instead of GNU inline semantics.

This means `inline`, `static inline` and `extern inline` all behave differently. In particular, `inline` expects an external definition in a separate translation unit (which you can provide without duplicating the definition - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245669/48015)).

Answer (score 7):

None of the above answers had given **exact working solution**!

Use `static inline` to avoid undefined or duplicate definition errors. `static inline` will behave like `inline` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function#C99
In C99, a function defined inline **will never**, and a function defined extern inline **will always**, emit an externally visible function. Unlike in C++, there is no way to ask for an externally visible function shared among translation units to be emitted only if required.

So to fix this error, just add extern inline for this function

Comment: No, it's better to add `static inline` to pursue C++ behavior. `extern inline` will generate duplicate errors if header is included from multiple sources.