# inline definition causes unresolved symbols in program

Tags: c

So I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(a,b) (a) > (b) ? a : b

int abs(int a)
{
    if (a > 0)
        return a;
    else
        return a*-1;
}

inline int avg(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b)/2;
}

int math_max(int a, int b)
{
    return (avg(a,b)+abs(avg(a,b)-b));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it: `gcc -g test.c -o test` I get:

```
/tmp/ccZbHEju.o: In function `math_max':
test.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `avg'
test.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `avg'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can fix this by removing the inline notation from avg, but I don't know why I'm getting undefined references if its inline - I thought the compiler was supposed to take care of that

Anyone care to explain?

** **Adding more information** **
For those who can't reproduce, I'm using:
`gcc --version gcc (GCC) 5.3.0 Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software
Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying
conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Compiling this code with without linking generates the following:

```
[ishaypeled@arania test]$ gcc -c test.c -o ./test.o
[ishaypeled@arania test]$ readelf -s ./test.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name  
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND   
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test.c  
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1   
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3   
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4  
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6  
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7  
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5  
     8: 0000000000000000    25 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 abs  
     9: 0000000000000019    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 max  
    10: 0000000000000044    69 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 math_max  
    11: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND avg  
    12: 0000000000000089    18 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main
```

Which clearly shows avg as NOTYPE and UND - this is why the linker failed... I have no idea why that happens. I also examined the preprocessor output from gcc:

[ishaypeled@arania test]$ gcc test.c -E

```
# 5 "test.c"
int abs(int a)
{
    if (a > 0)
        return a;
    else
        return a*-1;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return ((a+b)+abs(a-b))/2;
}

inline int avg(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b)/2;
}

int math_max(int a, int b)
{
    int avg_calc = avg(a,b);
    int distance_from_avg = abs(avg_calc-a);
    int res = avg_calc+distance_from_avg;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
# 44 "test.c"
    return 0;
}
```

Looks perfectly fine, avg appears before the usage in math_max.

`STDC version: 201112
__GNUC__ defined`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure this exact code was in a single source file, *in this exact order*?

Comment: There shouldn't be any error if the functions are not called in the main.

Comment: This is generally a problem if/when GCC is compiling in `-std=c99` mode. It usually isn't by default, but perhaps things have changed in modern GCC (assuming you're using a recent version). Try adding `int avg(int,int);` *after* your initial declaration for `avg()`.

Comment: @EOF: More importantly, is he using these *exact flags*? Because this usually *does not* compile in C99 or C11 mode.

Comment: Addendum: Can you show me what you get with `printf("%ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__);`, and can you check if `__GNUC__` is defined?

Comment: @EOF: Even if you also use the function? (note that without LTO, OP's `math_max()` function probably counts as using `avg()`!). It does not for me, with C99. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245521/c99-inline-function-in-c-file/16245669).

Comment: @TimČas: I'm too used to compile with `-O3`, which makes this compile...

Comment: @EOF: Probably because it removes `math_max()`, and with it the call to `avg()`, entirely. Try omitting that. As an experiment, you could try to remove its definition, that is, changing `avg()` into `int avg(int,int);` and ***removing*** the `inline avg(...){...}` part. If it still compiles that way, then it's compiling *only* because `-O3` removes every reference to `avg()`.

Comment: @EOF Did you manage to reproduce?

Comment: @TimČas I updated the information you requested in the post

Comment: I think you'll find here the explanation: [undefined-reference-when-calling-inline-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068705/undefined-reference-when-calling-inline-function)

Comment: Have you tried adding `static` before `inline`?

Comment: This is the behavior of a language standard and a compiler without a 1-800 support phone number :)  C99 requires you to explicitly state which TU contains the definition of the inline function.  That requires the highly intuitive `extern inline int avg(int a, int b);` in your source code file.

Comment: @HansPassant: So both `static inline` or `extern inline` will work, but plain `inline` is parsed, compiled and ignored?

Comment: It is not ignored, that would cause a compile error.  It doesn't get linked.  This only ever makes sense when you are a member of an ISO committee that finds a compromise by making everybody equally unhappy.

Comment: @HansPassant. The body of the plain inline function is ignored, it works just as a prototype for the function. In fact, I've replaced the inline function with a function prototype and the generated code is identical.

Comment: I accepted the duplicate suggestion as the answer (or at least the confirmation) exists in the proposed DUP, but I really don't understand the motivation behind this decision, which is actually what I'm asking