# undefined reference for inline function

Tags: c, linux, gcc, inline

I have composed below small program to explain the issue,

```
#include<stdio.h>

inline void test() {
        printf("test inline\n");
        return;
}
int main () {
        test();
        return 0;
}
```

While compiling it gives below error.

```
jeegarp@jeegarp:~$ gcc test.c 
/tmp/ccrpsWXN.o: In function `main':
4.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `test'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Now if i mark my inline function as static then i do not see this error.**

I am not able to understand this  observation.

Does it compiler specific issue?

Comment: Fails with 1) name other than `test` 2) without `inline`?

Comment: @chux it fails with other name also. It woks fine without inline keyword

Comment: @dbush IMO, that's a bad dupe.  This is much better:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245521/c99-inline-function-in-c-file/16245669#16245669 And even there, there are no cites to the C standard.

Comment: And the comments on this question are worth reading:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613360/inline-definition-causes-unresolved-symbols-in-program?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Surprising i am able to compile this file as gcc  -std=gnu89  test.c  or gcc  -O2  test.c