# Separate inline class member function declaration and definition to different files (header and source)

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have 3 files: **main.cpp**, **gp_frame.cpp** and **gp_frame.h**. I wish to declare a class (named gp_frame) in **gp_frame.h** and define the member functions in **gp_frame.cpp** and want to use the class in **main.cpp**.

Broadly, the three files:

```
/*main.cpp*/
#include "gp_frame.h"

void plotpicture(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c, unsigned int d, unsigned int e){
 anita.wait_enter("Some string\n");
}

int main(){
 gp_frame anita(true);
 plotpicture(1,2,3,4);
 return 0;
}

/*gp_frame.h*/

class gp_frame{
 public: void wait_enter(std::string uzi);
 gp_frame();
 gp_frame(bool isPersist);
};

/*gp_frame.cpp*/
#include "gp_frame.h"

void gp_frame::wait_enter(std::string uzi){
 /*Some of code*/
}
gp_frame::gp_frame(){
 /*Some of code*/
}
gp_frame::gp_frame(bool isPersist){
 /*Some of code*/
}
```

Then, I want to compile and link the files:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -w -Wall
g++ -c gp_frame.cpp -w -Wall
g++ gp_frame.o main.o -o Myprogram
```

And **everything is OK**. However, if I want to declare/define function *wait_enter* as `inline` like:

```
/*in gp_frame.h*/
public: inline void wait_enter(std::string uzi);
/*in gp_frame.cpp*/
inline void gp_frame::wait_enter(std::string uzi){
 /*Some of code*/
}
```

the compiler works as well, but the linker throws me an error:

```
main.o: In function `plotpicture(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2c6b): undefined reference to `gp_frame::wait_enter(std::string)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can you explain me how to solve the problem or what do I wrong?

---

Sadly, neither `extern inline` nor `static inline` solves my problem.

Comment: Inline functions must be defined in the header. It does not make sense to have an inline function that is defined only in the implementation. How can the compiler see the definition to inline it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference when calling inline function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068705/undefined-reference-when-calling-inline-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what do I wrong?

You declare an inline function `gp_frame::wait_enter(std::string)`, but you didn't define the function in all of the compilation units (source files) that use the function which is required by the standard.

In particular, you only defined the function in `gp_frame.cpp` but not in `main.cpp`, even though you do use the function in `main.cpp`.

> how to solve the problem

Define inline functions in all compilation units that use them. The idiomatic way to do that is to define them in the same header that also declares them (`gp_frame.h` in this case).