# Why inline would make a simple program not working?

Tags: c, inline

I have the following simple C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

INLINE void print(const char *s) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main() {
    print("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

But I got the following error if I define `INLINE` as `inline`. I don't understand the first run fails. My understanding is that the `print()` function should be inlined in `main()` at the compile time, so there should not be a link error complaining about the undefined reference to `print`. Could anybody help me understand why inlining would make it not working? `clang` also gives a similar error. Thanks.

```
$ gcc -DINLINE=inline -o main.exe main.c
/tmp/mktemp/ccSbK5B8.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ gcc -DINLINE= -o main.exe main.c
```

EDIT: But with -O2 the keyword `static` is not required. why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C99 referring to inline function: undefined reference to XXX and why should I put it to header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635665/c99-referring-to-inline-function-undefined-reference-to-xxx-and-why-should-i-pu).  The tl;dr is you need `static inline`.

Comment: it is not the dupe as inline does not work without the optimisation enabled. with -O0 you  will get this error.

Comment: @P__J__ of course it is the dupe.

Comment: @P__J__ I'm inclined to think it *should* be considered a dupe. Sure `-O1` might fix the error, and you can add that as an answer to the other questions, but I think code should preferably be made to work at all optimization levels.

Comment: @PSkocik it is very common trap :). inline and -O0 :). inline functions do not generste linkable code, and the code itself do not inline functions :) and we have  undefined reference

Comment: @P__J__ but this is about not understanding the `inline` keyword at all.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @P__J__ `inline` is still a hint. Linking can fail with even `-O42` if the compiler thinks it is not worth inlining the function

Comment: from gcc documentation:  `Inlining of functions is an optimization and it really “works” only in optimizing compilation. If you don't use -O, no function is really inline.` BTW to make sure that the function will be 100% inlined you need to use __attribute__((always_inline))

Comment: @AnttiHaapala no - if the inline function with the optimisation will not be inlined it will generate the linkable object code - test it yourself. At least gcc as do not use other compilers

Comment: @P__J__ [it doesn't, this is not how C works](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4p10). IIRC it was changed too...

Comment: @P__J__ afaik, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html - depends on mode. With gnu11, gcc should adhere to standard semantics.

Comment: @P__J__, it has nothing in particular to do with optimization.  An inline declaration of a function with external linkage *requires* an external definition of that function somewhere in in the program if that function is ever called.  If all of the declarations of a given function in a given translation unit specify `inline` but not `extern`, then that translation unit does not provide the required external definition.  That some compilers may nevertheless produce an executable from such code under some circumstances does not make that code even conditionally correct.