# calling a function from a .h file

Tags: c, function, struct

`file1.c` => includes `file1.h`

`file1.h` => has a `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned char *start;
  unsigned int startInt;
}debugPrint;
```

`file1.c` => creates a `struct` object:

```
debugPrint dp;
```

`file1.c` => an `int` is given into `struct`:

```
dp.startInt = 10;
```

`file1.c` => has a function:

```
void function1(debugPrint dp) {
  printf("%d", dp.startInt);
}
```

`file2.h` => has a function call to `file1.`c function which is declared before the call:

```
void function1(void);

function1();
```

Questions is:

- Is it ok that the file2.h calls a function from file1.c
- how can i pass the dp.startInt value to file2.h so that the value 10 that was set into dp.startInt in file1.c can be used in the funtion call in file2.h ?

It is needed to be called from file2.h since this file handles dynamic variable exchange between a html page and the file2.h file => data from file2.h function call via file1.c is sent to Html page. But i wont go more into the passing variable to html page since i don't know how it is made. It is a mechanism of openPicus web server example.

But if you know a good solution for this one. i would appreciate it. I'm not so familiar with this kind of code so that is also an issue here :)

But since i think this description is not good enough, here is the files:

file1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test1.h"

// Define printStruct
void printStruct (debugPrint dp) {
    printf("%u", dp.startInt);
}

int main ()
{
    dp.startInt = 10;
    getch();
}
```

file1.h:

```
typedef struct {
    // For the motorEncoder value
    unsigned char filename[20];
    char ownMsg[10];
    unsigned char *start;
    unsigned char *timeInSeconds;
    unsigned char *distanceInCm;
    unsigned char *numberOfShots;
    unsigned char *shutterCompensation;
    unsigned char *direction;
    unsigned char *cancel;
    unsigned char *dutyCycle;
    unsigned int cancelInt;
    unsigned int startInt;
    unsigned int dutyCycleInt;
    unsigned int directionInt;
}debugPrint;

// Create struct object called dp
debugPrint dp;

// declare printStruct
void printStruct (debugPrint dp);
```

file2.h: (this file is totally needed to pass the dynamic values) I didn't put any includes since im not sure how i should include the .h files and from where i should include them.

```
// Call printStruct function
printStruct(dp);
```

part of file2.h actual code: (AND YES file2.h A HEADER FILE). FOR ME THIS SEEMS LIKE THE FUNCTIONS ARE FIRST DECLARED AND THEN ONE OF THEM IS USED IN THE H FILE => the HTTPPrint() function from where a function called HTTPPrint_stepCounter(); is called. That function is defined then in file1.c and it just prints some dynamic data to a http page. And as said this is how openPicus has done it and i am just trying to modify it.

```
void HTTPPrint(DWORD callbackID);
void HTTPPrint_led(WORD);
void HTTPPrint_stepCounter(void);

void HTTPPrint(DWORD callbackID)
{
    switch(callbackID)
    {
        case 0x00000017:
            HTTPPrint_led(0);
            break;
        case 0x00000059:
            HTTPPrint_stepCounter();
            break;
        default:
            // Output notification for undefined values
            TCPPutROMArray(sktHTTP, (ROM BYTE*)"!DEF", 4);
    }

    return;
}

void HTTPPrint_(void)
{
    TCPPut(sktHTTP, '~');
    return;
}
```

Comment: You left out file2.h in your source post. Not some pseudo version please; the **real** code.

Comment: Your `file1.c` includes `test1.h`; is that what you're showing as `file1.h`?  The code shown doesn't use `file2.h`.  What is its relevance?  Note that headers should *not* normally contain function implementations; those belong in `.c` files.  The only exception is for `inline` functions, but those have complexities of their own.  (See [Is `inline` without `static` or `extern` ever useful in C99?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597/is-inline-without-static-or-extern-ever-useful-in-c99) for some information on `inline` functions; there are more questions like that, I'm sure.)

Comment: Yes i have understood also tha h files should not have function definitions or calls but openPicus (www.openpicus.com) has done on .h file accoringly as shown as last code in description. And that is the main problem i have (i think). Maybe if could find what file is sourcing the .h file that has the function calls etc. i could fix the issue. The problem is also that openpicus ide hides most of the used source files so i have to find the related files manually. But for now i removed the struct and just import many variables into the function. Its ugly but it seems to compile.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You claim that `file2.h` contains:</s>

```
void function(void);

function1();
```

But these lines refer to two different functions.
<sup>This problem is now fixed; both names are `function1`</sup>

If the `function1();` appears outside any function, it is a (very sloppy) function declaration, not a function call.  If it is inside some function, what is that function definition doing inside the header file.  It would need to be an `inline` function to have much legitimacy.

<sup>The problem below is now fixed; the types are consistent.</sup>

<s>Additionally, you say: *an integer is given into struct: `dp[1].startInt = 10;`*. The compiler complains that you shouldn't assign integers to pointers (since `startInt` is declared as a pointer, not an `int`).  You need to get your code to compile without such complaints.</s>

... *There are two versions of the structure defined, one at the top of the question where `startInt` is an `unsigned int *startInt;` and one later on where the declaration is `unsigned int startInt`.  Please make your question self-consistent!* ...

<sup>This problem has been fixed now; `dp` is a simple structure.</sup>

<s>Also note that you created `debugPrint dp[1];` so your initialization is trampling out of bounds; the maximum valid index for the array is 0.</s>

If code in `file2.c` needs to access the internals of the structure type declared in `file1.h`, the header `file1.h` should be included in `file2.c`.  You can declare your `dp` array in the header too.  A header should include other headers only if the functions it defines expose types defined in the other headers.  For example, if the structure defined in `file1.h` included a `FILE *db_fp;` element, then `file1.h` should `#include <stdio.h>` to ensure that the code in `file1.h` would compile regardless of what else the code using `file1.h` includes.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the inconsistent descriptions. The startInt shall not be a pointer but rather unsigned int startInt;

There is only file1.c and 2 header files file1.h and file2.h from where file2.h makes a function call. I can post the real code here what is coded into file2.h.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips for someone new to the C language:

There's an important difference between **definition** and **declaration**.

**Definition** is what actually creates the function or variable. Each function must be defined exactly once. Either in a *.c source file, or in a library.

**Declaration** creates an entry in the symbol table, that says the function or variable exists... somewhere... and here's its data type. Declarations can be duplicated without any effect.

We put function definitions in *.c source files. (And also in libraries, but that's an advanced build topic...)

We put public or `extern` function declarations in *.h header files.
We put shared `extern` variable declarations in *.h header files, so that other source units can share the same variable.
We put shared `typedef` structure declarations in *.h header files, so that other source units can share the same data type.

We do not put variable declarations in *.h header files if they aren't `extern`, or if they are initialized. The initial value belongs in the *.c file.

Function definitions usually don't belong in a *.h header file, because it's possible in a large project, that the header file could be included (read by the compiler) more than once. That would cause a compiler error, because then there would be more than one definition of that function. Even if it's literally a repeat of the same source code, there can be only one.

The quote about file2.h having a function call to file1.c function is not correct, `function1();` could be either a declaration or a function call depending on context:

```
// declaration of a function named foo
void foo(void);
//
// declaration of a function named bar
// equivalent to declaring void bar(void);
bar();
//
// definition of a function named foo
void foo(void)
{
    // call (or invoke) the function named bar
    bar();
}
```

Another small point, about arrays: it's pretty strange to declare an array of one element `debugPrint dp[1]`, since that declaration creates an object that will be referred to as `dp[0]`. This makes me think you may be trying to avoid the use of pointers... it would be more straightforward to just declare `debugPrint dp` and then the object is referred to as `dp`. Arrays make sense if you have more than one related object of the same type, but for just one object, it's a pretty unusual usage.

C is a very flexible programming language that gives free access to lots of low-level tricks. Both a blessing and a curse... For someone just getting started with the language, it's important to read other people's code examples as much as you can, to help learn how things are usually done. There are lots of extremely clever ways to use the language (e.g. Duff's Device) but in most cases, you're better off sticking with the most straightforward and customary way of solving the problem.

See also: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632)

Comment: Hi,

i changed the object to dp but when i try to use the dp in a function call => printStruct(dp); i get error

: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printStruct'

Comment: i got it fixed, i changed the declaration and definition of printStruct to printStruct(debugPrint dp);
I will change the description code accordingly.