# GCC inline C function causes error

Tags: c, gcc

This is strange to me.

```
inline complex_t complex_add(complex_t a, complex_t b)
{
    complex_t r = {a.re + b.re, a.im + b.im};
    return r;
}

inline complex_t complex_subtract(complex_t a, complex_t b)
{
    complex_t r = {a.re - b.re, a.im - b.im};
    return r;
}


inline complex_t complex_multiply(complex_t a, complex_t b)
{
    complex_t r = {a.re * b.re - a.im * b.im, a.re * b.im + a.im * b.re};
    return r;
}

inline complex_t complex_conjugate(complex_t a)
{
    complex_t r = {a.re, -a.im};
    return r;
}

inline complex_t complex_divide(complex_t a, complex_t b)
{
    float dem = b.im * b.im + b.re * b.re;

    complex_t r = complex_multiply(a, complex_conjugate(b));
    r.re /= dem;
    r.im /= dem;
    return r;
}

int divergence(double x, double y, int iters, complex_t* r)
{
    const complex_t c = {x, y};
    complex_t z = {0, 0};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < iters && complex_mag(z) < 2; i++)
    {
        z = complex_add(complex_multiply(z, z), c);
    }
    *r = z;
    return i;
}
```

When I compile this code I get the following error in the line `z = complex_add(complex_multiply(z, z), c)`...

```
home/chase/workspace/MandelbrotSet/Debug/../main.c:62: undefined reference to `complex_multiply'
makefile:44: recipe for target 'MandelbrotSet' failed
/home/chase/workspace/MandelbrotSet/Debug/../main.c:62: undefined reference to `complex_add'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MandelbrotSet] Error 1
```

However when I remove inline from the complex number functions the code compiles fine.  Any ideas why?  How come adding the inline makes it so the compiler can not find the function?

Comment: Which compiler flags are you using? (the behaviour of `inline` differs between C90, C99, and GNU89)

Comment: `inline` is `static` (file scope).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no it isn't

Comment: Also you willl need to indicate where this code fits into your project structure. For example if these function bodies were in a `.c` file and you tried to call them from a different `.c` file you would get undefined reference errors

Comment: inline doesn't happen at link time. where did you put your inline function?

Comment: Everything is in the same c file.  I just tested it.  It works with c90 but not c99.  Why?

Comment: @chasep255 As Matt McNabb said, the behaviour of `inline` in gcc varies depending on the language you select. Specifically, there is the GNU behaviour and the C99 behaviour. Consult the gcc manual for more details.

Comment: try `inline` --> `inline static`

Comment: C90 did not have `inline`. So it cannot work in C90.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `static` [should preceed](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.5) the function specifier actually.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to suggest that `inline`ing these functions will significantly improve the performance of your program?

Comment: "Everything is in the same c file" - ok, so your code is the same structure as the example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597/is-inline-without-static-or-extern-ever-useful-in-c99) which has links to some very detailed explanations