# __attribute__((weak)) and static libraries

Tags: c++, g++

I wanted to introduce a weak symbol into my code, however, I am unable to comprehend its behavior when *.a files are used.

This is my minimal example:

*file a.h:*

```
void foo() __attribute__((weak));
```

*file a.c:*

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() { printf("%s\n", __FILE__); }
```

*file b.c:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() { printf("%s\n", __FILE__); }
```

*file main.cpp:*

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { if (foo) foo(); else printf("no foo\n"); }
```

Now, depending if I use *.o  files (`make -c a.c` and `make -c b.c`) or *.a files (`ar cr a.o` and `ar cr b.o`) the output is different:

1) `g++ main.cpp a.o b.o` prints *b.c*
2) `g++ main.cpp b.o a.o` prints *b.c*
3) `g++ main.cpp a.a b.a` prints *no foo*
4) `g++ main.cpp b.a a.a` prints *no foo*

*1)*, *2)* work just fine but the output for *3)*, *4)* seems to be a little unexpected.

I was desperately trying to make this example work with archives so I made few changes:

*file a.h:*

```
void foo();
```

*file a.c:*

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__((weak)) foo() { printf("%s\n", __FILE__); }
```

After this modification:

1) `g++ main.cpp a.a b.a` prints *a.c*
2) `g++ main.cpp b.a a.a` prints *b.c*

So it works a bit better. After running `nm a.a` shows `W _Z3foov` so there is no violation of ODR. However, I don't know if this is a correct usage of *weak* attribute. According to gcc documentation:

> The weak attribute causes the ***declaration*** to be emitted as a weak symbol rather than a global. This is primarily useful in defining library functions which can be overridden in user code, though it can also be used with non-function declarations. Weak symbols are supported for ELF targets, and also for a.out targets when using the GNU assembler and linker.

Yet I use *weak* attribute on the function definition not the declaration.

So the question is why *weak* doesn't work with *.a files? Is usage of *weak* attribute on a definition instead of a declaration correct?

**UPDATE**

It has dawned on me that *weak* attribute used with *foo()* method definition had no impact on the symbol resolution. Without the attribute final binary generates the same:

1) `g++ main.cpp a.a b.a` prints *a.c*
2) `g++ main.cpp b.a a.a` prints *b.c*

So simply the first definition of the symbol is used and this is consisten with default gcc behaviour. Even though `nm a.a` shows that a weak symbol was emitted, it doesn't seem to affect static linking.

Is it possible to use *weak* attribute with static linking at all?

**DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM I WANT TO SOLVE**

I have a library that is used by >20 clients, let's call it library A. I also provide a library B which contains testing utils for A. Somehow I need to know that library A is used in testing mode, so the simplest solution seems to be replacing a symbol during linking with B (because clients are already linking with B).

I know there are cleaner solutions to this problem, however I absolutely can't impact clients' code or their build scripts (adding parameter that would indicate testing for A or some DEFINE for compilation is out of option).

Comment: I sniff XY problem. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to override original function implementation when linking with a testing framework. Previously I have dealt with similar issues using global variables, however, this is a fragile solution due to an undefined order of global initialization.

Comment: Use objcopy for that. Replace or remove original function implementation from the framework or set the original function as weak using objcopy. You don't need to recompile library, thus impact compilation process of the original framework. ex. `objcopy -N foo a.o`

Comment: How did you get it to output `no foo`? I can't reproduce it. In case of missing foo symbol the linker should emit an error, the foo symbol can't be equal to false, unless you somewhere define `void (*foo)() = 0;`.  Did you use a C++ compiler with a C symbols? If you used `make -c ` that usually runs a C compiler `cc` which creates a `foo` symbol, not a C++ `_Z3foov` symbol.

Comment: To generate `no foo` output I have used following commands:
`g++ -c a.c`
`ar cr a.a a.o`
`g++ -c b.c`
`ar cr b.a b.o`
`g++ main.cpp a.a b.a`

About the `void (*foo)() = 0;` as Mike Kinghan has already mentioned, a weak symbol may be left undefined then its value is assumed to be 0. I have used g++ all the time. I have mixed c and cpp extensions by mistake when writing this post. This isn't an issue in my original project.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To explain what's going on here, let's talk first about your original source files, with

**a.h (1)**:

```
void foo() __attribute__((weak));
```

and:

**a.c (1)**:

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() { printf("%s\n", __FILE__); }
```

The mixture of `.c` and `.cpp` files in your sample code is irrelevant to the
issues, and all the code is C, so we'll say that `main.cpp` is `main.c` and
do all compiling and linking with `gcc`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c a.c b.c
ar rcs a.a a.o
ar rcs b.a b.o
```

First let's review the differences between a weakly declared symbol, like
your:

```
void foo() __attribute__((weak));
```

and a strongly declared symbol, like

```
void foo();
```

which is the default:

- When a weak reference to `foo` (i.e. a reference to weakly declared `foo`) is linked in a program, the
  linker need not find a definition of `foo` anywhere in the linkage: it may remain
  undefined. If a strong reference to `foo` is linked in a program,
  the linker needs to find a definition of `foo`.
- A linkage may contain at most one strong definition of `foo` (i.e. a definition
  of `foo` that declares it strongly). Otherwise a multiple-definition error results.
  But it may contain multiple weak definitions of `foo` without error.
- If a linkage contains one or more weak definitions of `foo` and also a strong
  definition, then the linker chooses the strong definition and ignores the weak
  ones.
- If a linkage contains just one weak definition of `foo` and no strong
  definition, inevitably the linker uses the one weak definition.
- If a linkage contains multiple weak definitions of `foo` and no strong
  definition, then the linker chooses one of the weak definitions *arbitrarily*.

Next, let's review the differences between inputting an object file in a linkage
and inputting a static library.

A static library is merely an `ar` archive of object files that we may offer to
the linker from which to select the ones it *needs* to carry on the linkage.

When an object file is input to a linkage, the linker unconditionally links it
into the output file.

When static library is input to a linkage, the linker examines the archive to
find any object files within it that provide definitions *it needs* for unresolved symbol references
that have accrued from input files already linked. If it finds any such object files
in the archive, it extracts them and links them into the output file, exactly as
if they were individually named input files and the static library was not mentioned at all.

With these observations in mind, consider the compile-and-link command:

```
gcc main.c a.o b.o
```

Behind the scenes `gcc` breaks it down, as it must, into a compile-step and link
step, just as if you had run:

```
gcc -c main.c     # compile
gcc main.o a.o b.o  # link
```

All three object files are linked unconditionally into the (default) program `./a.out`. `a.o` contains a
weak definition of `foo`, as we can see:

```
$ nm --defined a.o
0000000000000000 W foo
```

Whereas `b.o` contains a strong definition:

```
$ nm --defined b.o
0000000000000000 T foo
```

The linker will find both definitions and choose the strong one from `b.o`, as we can
also see:

```
$ gcc main.o a.o b.o -Wl,-trace-symbol=foo
main.o: reference to foo
a.o: definition of foo
b.o: definition of foo
$ ./a.out
b.c
```

Reversing the linkage order of `a.o` and `b.o` will make no difference: there's
still exactly one strong definition of `foo`, the one in `b.o`.

By contrast consider the compile-and-link command:

```
gcc main.cpp a.a b.a
```

which breaks down into:

```
gcc -c main.cpp     # compile
gcc main.o a.a b.a  # link
```

Here, only `main.o` is linked unconditionally. That puts an undefined weak reference
to `foo` into the linkage:

```
$ nm --undefined main.o
                 w foo
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
```

That weak reference to `foo` *does not need a definition*. So the linker will
not attempt to find a definition that resolves it in any of the object files in either `a.a` or `b.a` and
will leave it undefined in the program, as we can see:

```
$ gcc main.o a.a b.a -Wl,-trace-symbol=foo
main.o: reference to foo
$ nm --undefined a.out
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w foo
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Hence:

```
$ ./a.out
no foo
```

Again, it doesn't matter if you reverse the linkage order of `a.a` and `b.a`,
but this time it is because neither of them contributes anything to the linkage.

Let's turn now to the different behavior you discovered by changing `a.h` and `a.c`
to:

**a.h (2)**:

```
void foo();
```

**a.c (2)**:

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__((weak)) foo() { printf("%s\n", __FILE__); }
```

Once again:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c a.c b.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:18: warning: the address of ‘foo’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
 int main() { if (foo) foo(); else printf("no foo\n"); }
```

See that warning? `main.o` now contains a *strongly* declared reference to `foo`:

```
$ nm --undefined main.o
                 U foo
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

so the code (when linked) *must have* a non-null address for `foo`. Proceeding:

```
$ ar rcs a.a a.o
$ ar rcs b.a b.o
```

Then try the linkage:

```
$ gcc main.o a.o b.o
$ ./a.out
b.c
```

And with the object files reversed:

```
$ gcc main.o b.o a.o
$ ./a.out
b.c
```

As before, the order makes no difference. All the object files are linked. `b.o` provides
a strong definition of `foo`, `a.o` provides a weak one, so `b.o` wins.

Next try the linkage:

```
$ gcc main.o a.a b.a
$ ./a.out
a.c
```

And with the order of the libraries reversed:

```
$ gcc main.o b.a a.a
$ ./a.out
b.c
```

That *does* make a difference. Why? Let's redo the linkages with diagnostics:

```
$ gcc main.o a.a b.a -Wl,-trace,-trace-symbol=foo
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
main.o
(a.a)a.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
main.o: reference to foo
a.a(a.o): definition of foo
```

Ignoring the default libraries, the only object files of *ours* that get
linked were:

```
main.o
(a.a)a.o
```

And the definition of `foo` was taken from the archive member `a.o` of `a.a`:

```
a.a(a.o): definition of foo
```

Reversing the library order:

```
$ gcc main.o b.a a.a -Wl,-trace,-trace-symbol=foo
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
main.o
(b.a)b.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
main.o: reference to foo
b.a(b.o): definition of foo
```

This time the object files linked were:

```
main.o
(b.a)b.o
```

And the definition of `foo` was taken from `b.o` in `b.a`:

```
b.a(b.o): definition of foo
```

In the first linkage, the linker had an unresolved strong reference to
`foo` for which it needed a definition when it reached `a.a`. So it
looked in the archive for an object file that provides a definition,
and found `a.o`. That definition was a weak one, but that didn't matter. No
strong definition had been seen. `a.o` was extracted from `a.a` and linked,
and the reference to `foo` was thus resolved. Next `b.a` was reached, where
a strong definition of `foo` *would* have been found in `b.o`, if the linker still needed one
and looked for it. But it didn't need one any more and didn't look. The linkage:

```
gcc main.o a.a b.a
```

is *exactly the same* as:

```
gcc main.o a.o
```

And likewise the linkage:

```
$ gcc main.o b.a a.a
```

is exactly the same as:

```
$ gcc main.o b.o
```

**Your real problem...**

... emerges in one of your comments to the post:

> I want to override [the] original function implementation when linking with a testing framework.

You want to link a program inputting some static library `lib1.a`
which has some member `file1.o` that defines a symbol `foo`, and you want to knock out
that definition of `foo` and link a different one that is defined in some other object
file `file2.o`.

`__attribute__((weak))` isn't applicable to that problem. The solution is more
elementary. *You just make sure to input* `file2.o` *to the linkage before you input*
`lib1.a` (and before any other input that provides a definition of `foo`).
Then the linker will resolve references to `foo` with the definition provided in `file2.o` and will not try to find any other
definition when it reaches `lib1.a`. The linker will not consume `lib1.a(file1.o)` at all. It might as well not exist.

And what if you have put `file2.o` in another static library `lib2.a`? Then inputting
`lib2.a` before `lib1.a` will do the job of linking `lib2.a(file2.o)` before
`lib1.a` is reached and resolving `foo` to the definition in `file2.o`.

Likewise, of course, *every* definition provided by members of `lib2.a` will be linked in
preference to a definition of the same symbol provided in `lib1.a`. If that's not what
you want, then don't link `lib2.a`: link `file2.o` itself.

**Finally**

> Is it possible to use [the] weak attribute with static linking at all?

Certainly. Here is a first-principles use-case:

**foo.h (1)**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

int __attribute__((weak)) foo(int i)
{
    return i != 0;
}

#endif
```

**aa.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int a(void)
{
    return foo(0);
}
```

**bb.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int b(void)
{
    return foo(42);
}
```

**prog.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a(void);
extern int b(void);

int main(void)
{
    puts(a() ? "true" : "false");
    puts(b() ? "true" : "false");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile all the source files, requesting a seperate ELF section for each function:

```
$ gcc -Wall -ffunction-sections -c prog.c aa.c bb.c
```

Note that the *weak* definition of `foo` is compiled via `foo.h` into *both*
`aa.o` and `bb.o`, as we can see:

```
$ nm --defined aa.o
0000000000000000 T a
0000000000000000 W foo
$ nm --defined bb.o
0000000000000000 T b
0000000000000000 W foo
```

Now link a program from all the object files, requesting the linker to
discard unused sections (and give us the map-file, and some diagnostics):

```
$ gcc prog.o aa.o bb.o -Wl,--gc-sections,-Map=mapfile,-trace,-trace-symbol=foo
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
prog.o
aa.o
bb.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
aa.o: definition of foo
```

This linkage is no different from:

```
$ ar rcs libaabb.a aa.o bb.o
$ gcc prog.o libaabb.a
```

Despite the fact that both `aa.o` and `bb.o` were loaded, and each contains
a definition of `foo`, no multiple-definition error results, because each definition
is *weak*. `aa.o` was loaded before `bb.o` and the definition of `foo` was linked from `aa.o`.

So what happened to the definition of `foo` in `bb.o`? The mapfile shows us:

**mapfile (1)**

```
...
...
Discarded input sections
...
...
 .text.foo      0x0000000000000000       0x13 bb.o
...
...
```

The linker discarded the function section that contained the definition
in `bb.o`

Let's reverse the linkage order of `aa.o` and `bb.o`:

```
$ gcc prog.o bb.o aa.o -Wl,--gc-sections,-Map=mapfile,-trace,-trace-symbol=foo
...
prog.o
bb.o
aa.o
...
bb.o: definition of foo
```

And now the opposite thing happens. `bb.o` is loaded before `aa.o`. The
definition of `foo` is linked from `bb.o` and:

**mapfile (2)**

```
...
...
Discarded input sections
...
...
 .text.foo      0x0000000000000000       0x13 aa.o
...
...
```

the definition from `aa.o` is chucked away.

There you see how the linker *arbitrarily* chooses one of multiple
weak definitions of a symbol, in the absence of a strong definition. It simply
picks the first one you give it and ignores the rest.

What we've just done here is effectively what the GCC C++ compiler does for us when we
define a *global inline function*. Rewrite:

**foo.h (2)**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

inline int foo(int i)
{
    return i != 0;
}

#endif
```

Rename our source files `*.c` -> `*.cpp`; compile and link:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c prog.cpp aa.cpp bb.cpp
```

Now there is a weak definition of `foo` (C++ mangled) in each of `aa.o` and `bb.o`:

```
$ nm --defined aa.o bb.o

aa.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z1av
0000000000000000 W _Z3fooi

bb.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z1bv
0000000000000000 W _Z3fooi
```

The linkage uses the first definition it finds:

```
$ g++ prog.o aa.o bb.o -Wl,-Map=mapfile,-trace,-trace-symbol=_Z3fooi
...
prog.o
aa.o
bb.o
...
aa.o: definition of _Z3fooi
bb.o: reference to _Z3fooi
```

and throws away the other one:

**mapfile (3)**

```
...
...
Discarded input sections
...
...
 .text._Z3fooi  0x0000000000000000       0x13 bb.o
...
...
```

And as you may know, every instantiation of the C++ function template in
global scope (or instantiation of a class template member function) is
an *inline global function*. Rewrite again:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

template<typename T>
T foo(T i)
{
    return i != 0;
}

#endif
```

Recompile:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c prog.cpp aa.cpp bb.cpp
```

Again:

```
$ nm --defined aa.o bb.o

aa.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z1av
0000000000000000 W _Z3fooIiET_S0_

bb.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z1bv
0000000000000000 W _Z3fooIiET_S0_
```

each of `aa.o` and `bb.o` has a weak definition of:

```
$ c++filt _Z3fooIiET_S0_
int foo<int>(int)
```

and the linkage behaviour is now familiar. One way:

```
$ g++ prog.o aa.o bb.o -Wl,-Map=mapfile,-trace,-trace-symbol=_Z3fooIiET_S0_
...
prog.o
aa.o
bb.o
...
aa.o: definition of _Z3fooIiET_S0_
bb.o: reference to _Z3fooIiET_S0_
```

and the other way:

```
$ g++ prog.o bb.o aa.o -Wl,-Map=mapfile,-trace,-trace-symbol=_Z3fooIiET_S0_
...
prog.o
bb.o
aa.o
...
bb.o: definition of _Z3fooIiET_S0_
aa.o: reference to _Z3fooIiET_S0_
```

Our program's behavior is unchanged by the rewrites:

```
$ ./a.out
false
true
```

So the application of the *weak* attribute to symbols in the linkage of ELF objects -
whether static or dynamic - enables the GCC implementation of C++ templates
for the GNU linker. You could fairly say it enables the GCC implementation of modern C++.

Comment: Upvoted, however I don't like the last phrase about it enabling the GCC implementation of modern C++. It only enables inline functions to do the multiple definitions, and inline functions exist in C and have this behavior. Only templates (which are by default inline) are C++ specific. But then they get this behavior by being inline, and only indirectly by the weak linking.

Comment: @PaulStelian: GCC handles `inline` functions in C somewhat differently how it implements them in C++.  In C with `gcc`, you do need to instantiate a non-inline definition in exactly one `.c` file, like `extern inline void f();`.  See [Is "inline" without "static" or "extern" ever useful in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6312597) .  Otherwise, if the function doesn't get inlined at every call-site, you get a link error.

Comment: (Related: `gcc` recently changed to `-fno-common` so multiple non-tentative defs. for global vars are an error: [How throw a GCC error, if a global variable with the same name gets declared twice in a C/C++ file, but not static, extern, nor volatile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74412226).  I was thinking there was something like this for `inline` functions in C, but apparently I'm mistaken since people were getting linker errors before GCC10 without `extern inline` instantiation.

Answer (score 4):

I find that [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15833.html) is the best explanation:

> The linker will only search through libraries to resolve a reference if it cannot resolve that reference after searching all input objects. If required, the libraries are searched from left to right according to their position on the linker command line.  Objects within the library will be searched by the order in which they were archived.  As soon as armlink finds a symbol match for the reference, the searching is finished, even  if it matches a weak definition.
>   The ELF ABI section 4.6.1.2 says:
>   "A weak definition does not change the rules by which object files are selected from libraries. However, if a link set contains both a weak definition and a non-weak definition, the non-weak definition will always be used."
>   The "link set" is the set of objects that have been loaded by the linker. It does not include objects from libraries that are not required.
>   Therefore archiving two objects where one contains the weak definition of a given symbol and the other contains the non-weak definition of that symbol, into a library or separate libraries, is not recommended.

Observe the following. Basically renamed `mv a.c definition.c` `mv b.c noweak.c` and `mv second_a.c declaration.c`.

```
> for i in Makefile *.c; do echo "cat $i <<EOF"; cat $i; echo EOF; done
cat Makefile <<EOF
tgt=
tgt+=only_weak_1.out only_weak_2.out
tgt+=definition.out declaration.out noweak.out
tgt+=definition_static.out declaration_static.out noweak_static.out
tgt+=1.out 2.out 3.out 4.out
tgt+=5.out 6.out 7.out 8.out
tgt+=10.out 11.out 12.out
tgt+=13.out
tgt+=14.out

only_weak_1_obj= definition.o declaration.o
only_weak_2_obj= declaration.o definition.o
definition_obj= definition.o
declaration_obj= declaration.o
noweak_obj= noweak.o
definition_static_obj= definition.a
declaration_static_obj= declaration.a
noweak_static_obj= noweak.a
1_obj= declaration.o noweak.o
2_obj= noweak.o declaration.o
3_obj= declaration.a noweak.a
4_obj= noweak.a declaration.a
5_obj= definition.o noweak.o
6_obj= noweak.o definition.o
7_obj= definition.a noweak.a
8_obj= noweak.a definition.a
10_obj= noweak.a definition.a declaration.a
11_obj= definition.a declaration.a noweak.a
12_obj= declaration.a definition.a noweak.a
13_obj= all.a
14_obj= all.o


.PRECIOUS: % %.o %.c %.a
def: run
.PHONY: run
run: $(tgt)
    { $(foreach a,$^,echo "$($(a:.out=)_obj)#->#$(a)#:#$$(./$(a))";) } | { echo; column -t -s'#' -N 'objects, ,executable, ,output' -o' '; echo; }
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.out: main.o $$(%_obj) 
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $^
%.a: %.o
    ar cr $@ $^
all.a: declaration.o definition.o noweak.o
    ar cr $@ $^
all.o: declaration.o definition.o noweak.o
    $(LD) -i -o $@ $^
clean:
    rm -fv *.o *.a *.out
EOF
```

```
cat declaration.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((__weak__)) void foo();
void foo() { printf("%s\n", __FILE__); }
EOF
cat definition.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((__weak__)) void foo() { printf("%s\n", __FILE__); }
EOF
cat main.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
void foo();
int main() {
    if (foo) foo(); else printf("no foo\n");
    return 0;
}
EOF
cat noweak.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
void foo() { printf("%s\n", __FILE__); }
EOF
```

```
> make
cc -c -o definition.o definition.c
cc -c -o declaration.o declaration.c
cc -c -o main.o main.c
cc -o only_weak_1.out main.o definition.o declaration.o
cc -o only_weak_2.out main.o declaration.o definition.o
cc -o definition.out main.o definition.o
cc -o declaration.out main.o declaration.o
cc -c -o noweak.o noweak.c
cc -o noweak.out main.o noweak.o
ar cr definition.a definition.o
cc -o definition_static.out main.o definition.a
ar cr declaration.a declaration.o
cc -o declaration_static.out main.o declaration.a
ar cr noweak.a noweak.o
cc -o noweak_static.out main.o noweak.a
cc -o 1.out main.o declaration.o noweak.o
cc -o 2.out main.o noweak.o declaration.o
cc -o 3.out main.o declaration.a noweak.a
cc -o 4.out main.o noweak.a declaration.a
cc -o 5.out main.o definition.o noweak.o
cc -o 6.out main.o noweak.o definition.o
cc -o 7.out main.o definition.a noweak.a
cc -o 8.out main.o noweak.a definition.a
cc -o 10.out main.o noweak.a definition.a declaration.a
cc -o 11.out main.o definition.a declaration.a noweak.a
cc -o 12.out main.o declaration.a definition.a noweak.a
ar cr all.a declaration.o definition.o noweak.o
cc -o 13.out main.o all.a
ld -i -o all.o declaration.o definition.o noweak.o
cc -o 14.out main.o all.o
{ echo "definition.o declaration.o#->#only_weak_1.out#:#$(./only_weak_1.out)"; echo "declaration.o definition.o#->#only_weak_2.out#:#$(./only_weak_2.out)"; echo "definition.o#->#definition.out#:#$(./definition.out)"; echo "declaration.o#->#declaration.out#:#$(./declaration.out)"; echo "noweak.o#->#noweak.out#:#$(./noweak.out)"; echo "definition.a#->#definition_static.out#:#$(./definition_static.out)"; echo "declaration.a#->#declaration_static.out#:#$(./declaration_static.out)"; echo "noweak.a#->#noweak_static.out#:#$(./noweak_static.out)"; echo "declaration.o noweak.o#->#1.out#:#$(./1.out)"; echo "noweak.o declaration.o#->#2.out#:#$(./2.out)"; echo "declaration.a noweak.a#->#3.out#:#$(./3.out)"; echo "noweak.a declaration.a#->#4.out#:#$(./4.out)"; echo "definition.o noweak.o#->#5.out#:#$(./5.out)"; echo "noweak.o definition.o#->#6.out#:#$(./6.out)"; echo "definition.a noweak.a#->#7.out#:#$(./7.out)"; echo "noweak.a definition.a#->#8.out#:#$(./8.out)"; echo "noweak.a definition.a declaration.a#->#10.out#:#$(./10.out)"; echo "definition.a declaration.a noweak.a#->#11.out#:#$(./11.out)"; echo "declaration.a definition.a noweak.a#->#12.out#:#$(./12.out)"; echo "all.a#->#13.out#:#$(./13.out)"; echo "all.o#->#14.out#:#$(./14.out)"; } | { echo; column -t -s'#' -N 'objects, ,executable, ,output' -o' '; echo; }
```

```
objects                                executable               output
definition.o declaration.o          -> only_weak_1.out        : definition.c
declaration.o definition.o          -> only_weak_2.out        : declaration.c
definition.o                        -> definition.out         : definition.c
declaration.o                       -> declaration.out        : declaration.c
noweak.o                            -> noweak.out             : noweak.c
definition.a                        -> definition_static.out  : definition.c
declaration.a                       -> declaration_static.out : declaration.c
noweak.a                            -> noweak_static.out      : noweak.c
declaration.o noweak.o              -> 1.out                  : noweak.c
noweak.o declaration.o              -> 2.out                  : noweak.c
declaration.a noweak.a              -> 3.out                  : declaration.c
noweak.a declaration.a              -> 4.out                  : noweak.c
definition.o noweak.o               -> 5.out                  : noweak.c
noweak.o definition.o               -> 6.out                  : noweak.c
definition.a noweak.a               -> 7.out                  : definition.c
noweak.a definition.a               -> 8.out                  : noweak.c
noweak.a definition.a declaration.a -> 10.out                 : noweak.c
definition.a declaration.a noweak.a -> 11.out                 : definition.c
declaration.a definition.a noweak.a -> 12.out                 : declaration.c
all.a                               -> 13.out                 : declaration.c
all.o                               -> 14.out                 : noweak.c
```

In case only weak symbols are used (case only_weak_1 and only_weak_2) the first definition is used.
In case of only static libraries (case 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13) the first definition is used.
In case only object files are used (cases 1, 2, 5, 6, 14) the weak symbols are omitted and only the symbol from noweak is used.
From the link I provided:

> There are different ways to guarantee armlink selecting a non-weak version of a given symbol:
>   - Do not archive such objects
>   - Ensure that the weak and non-weak symbols are contained within the same object before archiving
>   - Use partial linking as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. So it is clear now that I can't use weak symbols with static libraries. Unfortunately, it seems that I don't achieve the desired result without impacting clients build systems.

Comment: You can remove the symbol using objcopy and then link with your implementation of foo. Using my code: `objcopy -Nfoo noweak.a; gcc -o main.out noweak.a declaration.a main.c` will remove the not weak symboll from noweak.a and then use the foo symbol from declaration.a ALWAYS.

Comment: Thank you for a great response :-)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. But the ARM link is broken.

Comment: The link in the original response is broken, and I can not find the new link. Has anybody managed to find it?

Comment: `Has anybody managed to find it?` I tried to search it some time ago, and I believe ARM just removed the info. That's why I copy stuff to my answers. Search on wayback machine.

Comment: `Ensure that the weak and non-weak symbols are contained within the same object before archiving`. This is fundamentally wrong