# Can't replace __weak function in static library, which wrapped in another static library with strong definition

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries, weak-references

Context: IAR ARM Compiler.

I'm trying to wrap hardware library ("STM32 HAL library") into library with my additions and link it to my executable.

As in scheme:

```
   /platform
    - /hal_library
    -  -  hal_source.c (with weak foo())
    -  hal_portable_source.c (with strong foo())
    -  platform.c (with strong foo())
   main.c
```

CMake has this structure (pseudo code):

```
    ### Hal_Library.cmake
    
    add_library(hal_lib ${HAL_SOURCES})
    target_include_directories(hal_lib ${HAL_HEADERS}

    ### Platform_Library.cmake

    include(Hal_Library.cmake)
    add_library(platform_lib ${PLATFORM_SOURCES})
    target_include_directories(platform_lib${PLATFORM_HEADERS}
    target_link_libraries(platform_lib hal_lib)

    ### CMakeLists.txt

    add_subdirectory(./platform)
    add_executable(my_app main.c)
    target_link_libraries(my_app platform_lib )
```

`hal_source.c` contain `__weak void Foo(void)`
AND! calls it in self functions. Vendor assume what user replace it with strong implementation `void Foo(void)` in his code. And it is works, when you add `strong_foo_realization.c` in executable directly.

But I'm trying to replace it in `platform_lib`  with `strong_foo_realization.c` added and where`hal_lib` is linked to.

And I get, what `__weak Foo()` is not replaced by mine strong `Foo()`.

Referring to `*.map` file, the `strong_foo_realization.c` is never been added.

I've read:

[__attribute__((weak)) and static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656838/attribute-weak-and-static-libraries)

and other topics, but seems there is no answer to my situation.

I've also tried:

- `--whole_archive` did not help
- Add all sources from `hal_lib` to `platform_lib` (and remove `hal_lib` at all). It didn't help
- Change the position of `hal_portable_source.c.o` in link command. It didn't help
- Same for library.

Comment: Where are `PLATFORM_SOURCES`, etc. variables defined?

Comment: In same files. In make this implicitly to not bloat the post. @kiner_shah

Comment: `--whole_archive did not help` Most probably you did not use it properly - it should have. Please show have have you used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is compiler problem. IAR dont works the way GCC does. There are no info how to make it work with IAR compiler.