# How to define a constant double at namespace scope with external linkage?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am trying to create a **namespace-scope** constant with **external linkage**

```
// in some include file:

namespace foo 
{
    constexpr double bar() { return 1.23456; } // internal linkage
    constexpr double baz = 1.23456;            // internal linkage
    const double bing = 1.23456;               // internal linkage
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: `const` or `constexpr`? Pick one.

Comment: They are very different. Let's pick one.

Comment: I am trying to create a namespace-scope constant with external linkage  - a solution which solves my problem, beit `const` or `constexpr`, will suffice.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need it to have external linkage.

Comment: @NicolBolas for a global constant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, and no**; you can use `extern`:

> `[C++11: 3.5/3]:` **A name having namespace scope** (3.3.6) **has internal linkage if it is the name of**
>
> - a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared `static`; or,
> - **a variable that is explicitly declared** `const` or **`constexpr`** and **neither explicitly declared `extern` nor previously declared to have external linkage**; or
> - a data member of an anonymous union.

So:

```
namespace foo 
{
    extern constexpr double bar() { return 1.23456; }
    extern constexpr double baz = 1.23456;
}
```

In your other translation unit, you should now be able to *declare* the function's name and refer to it:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo
{
   extern constexpr double bar();
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << foo::bar() << '\n';
}
```

However, the rules for `constexpr` *variables* state that [you cannot have a declaration that is not also a definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> `[C++11: 7.1.5/9]:` A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. *[..]*

So, you cannot take the same approach with `baz`.

Comment: What would happen if the file was included?

Comment: @RedXIII: Inclusion is irrelevant; `#include` is a strict text-based replacement performed by the pre-processor; this question relates to the compilation phases. i.e. you can replace every line of my example with an `#include` directive that refers to a file containing that line, if you like, but it won't change my answer. :)

Comment: I was referring to your comment that "*you cannot have a declaration that is not a definition for `constexpr`*". This way you wouldn't have to `extern` the externally implemented `constexpr` and thus use it.

Comment: @RedXIII: You mean you're talking about simply creating identical internal-linkage definitions for the symbol in each translation unit, using a header? Okay, yes, fine, but that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

`constexpr` for functions implies `inline`, which implies external linkage. So you already have what you want for `bar`. As for `baz` and `bing`, you can also declare them inline in C++17.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4193698/261217