# Undefined reference char*

Tags: c++, class

I have the following part of code in testtournamentmember.cpp

```
TournamentMember player1("Ian", "Smith", "1998-12-03");

TournamentMember player2 = TournamentMember(player1);
player1.setFirstName("Andrew");
```

with class TournamentMember.h defined as:

```
private:
char firstName[31];
char lastName[31];
char dateBirth[11];
static std::string location;
//static int numberMembers;
//static int difficulty;

public:
TournamentMember();
TournamentMember(char[], char[], char[]);
TournamentMember(const TournamentMember&);
~TournamentMember();

inline void setFirstName(char*);
```

and with TournamentMember.cpp with:

```
inline void TournamentMember::setFirstName(char* _firstName){
     strcpy(firstName, _firstName);
}
```

(I have all the other functions defined, but I didn't attached them). When I want to run the code, I receive undefined reference to 'TournamentMember::setFirtstName(char*). I do not understand what is wrong with my code, because I define the fuction setFirstName as char* in the class and also in the program.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386256/inline-functions-and-external-linkage

Comment: TournamentMember::set**Firtst**Name(char*) is certainly a typo (Firtst vs. First).  I can't reproduce it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `setFirstName` in TournamentMember.cpp is marked `inline`. That means the definition exists only in TournamentMember.cpp; that definition is not accessible from other source files, such as testtournamentmember.cpp.

By the way, you should be getting this error when you go to *compile* the code, not run it. You might be using a process that compiles and runs in one step, but you should still be aware of the distinction.