# ODR violation due to anonymous namespace in header

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, linkage, one-definition-rule, inline-functions

From reading the standard I was unable to figure out if the following code violates ODR:

```
// a.h
#ifndef A_HEADER_FILE
#define A_HEADER_FILE

namespace {
int v;
}

inline int get_v() { return v; }

#endif // A_HEADER_FILE

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"

void f() {
  int i = get_v();
  // ...
}

// b.cpp
#include "a.h"

void g() {
  int i = get_v();
  // ...
}
```

(Source: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/DCL59-CPP.+Do+not+define+an+unnamed+namespace+in+a+header+file)

Supposedly, `get_v()` references different variables in each translation unit so it violates `ODR`.

This answer: [Inline functions and external linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386256/inline-functions-and-external-linkage/16386407#16386407) says that inline relaxes `ODR` so I am not sure why this is still an error?

Can someone link me to where in the standard it is specified if this is an `ODR` violation or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `inline` function is allowed to have multiple definitions (C++17 [basic.def.odr]/6). This is the sense in which `inline` functions can be used to prevent ODR violations. However, the multiple definitions of the `inline` function must be consistent with each other. To be specific, [basic.def.odr]/6.2 says:

> in each definition of `D`, corresponding names, looked up according to 6.4, shall refer to an entity defined within the definition of `D`, or shall refer to the same entity [...] [some exceptions]

The multiple definitions of `get_v` refer to the variable `v`, but `v` is not defined within `get_v`. Therefore, it is required that each definition of `get_v` reference the same variable `v`. This is not the case, since each translation unit has a different `v`. Therefore, the ODR is violated.