Is the wording of C11 for inline functions strict?
This problem mainly concerns wording issues.
For inline functions and inline definitions, C11 describes them as follows:
6.7.4 p6:

A function declared with an inline function specifier is an inline
function.

and:
6.7.4 p7:

Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function. For a
function with external linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a
function is declared with an inline function specifier, then it shall
also be defined in the same translation unit. If all of the file scope
declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline
function specifier without extern, then the definition in that
translation unit is an inline definition.

First, for the sentence "Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function.",
To be frank, I think this sentence is correct but it is redundant.Because according to the definition of inline functions, as long as “inline” appears, then the function is an inline function.
Continue reading.
Combined with the previous text,My understanding of the following text is that if the restrictions mentioned in the standard are broken, then a function with external linkage will not be an inline function.
Obviously this is incorrect. Because whether a function is an inline function has nothing to do with its linkage. The words in 6.7.4 p10 also prove this point well:

The declaration of an inline function with external linkage can result
in either an external definition,or a definition available for use
only within the translation unit. A file scope declaration with extern
creates an external definition. The following example shows an entire
translation unit.···

"a definition available for use only within the translation unit",(1)I think this definition refers to the inline definition.
Then the bold part of this sentence indicates that an inline function can have an inline definition or an external definition.
So, (2)for part 6.7.4 p7, I guess the standard should want to say:

Any inline function with internal linkage has an inline definition.
For an inline function with external linkage,...

My question is, is there an error in my understanding of the places marked (1) and (2)?\
(3)6.7.4 p6:"Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to the function be as fast as possible".Does whether a function is inlined ultimately depend on whether the function is an inline function or on whether the function has an inline definition?
This may be a meaningless and boring question. But still, thank you for your reading.

Does your confusion come from the difference between "internal linkage" and "inline function specifier"? Because I don't see what you state as "[Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function] is correct but it is redundant". A function with internal linkage does not need to have the inline function specifier.

Would you mind to [edit] your question to add examples for each case, please?

"Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function.", To be frank, I think this sentence is correct but it is redundant." --> I do not find this redundant.  It means a static function, even without inline may become inline code rather than a true function call.

@the busybee:"Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function",My understanding of this sentence is that any function with internal linkage can have an “inline” added to make it an inline function.So I think this sentence is redundant because it must be so according to the definition of inline functions. Is there a problem with my understanding?

@chux - Reinstate Monica:I think the meaning of this sentence is: Any function with internal linkage may be declared  static inline  with no other restrictions.
Perhaps I am wrong?

The compiler decides whether a function with internal linkage is inlined or not. It does not have to have the inline function specifier. Additionally, the compiler is free to ignore that specifier. -- To clarify your understanding in detail, please provide the examples.

This related question may help the understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475308/in-c-should-inline-functions-in-headers-be-externed-in-the-c-file

@the busybee:Regarding the relevant doubts, I have raised a new question and provided a code example.

How does the new question differ from this one?


My understanding of the following text is that if the restrictions mentioned in the standard are broken, then a function with external linkage will not be an inline function.

Your understanding is wrong. It's not saying "if you break the restrictions, then ...". It's saying you must not break these restrictions. A program that violates these restrictions is not a valid C program.
A function with external linkage, declared with an inline function specifier, must also be defined in the same translation unit.

Yes. Then how should we understand the sentence "Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function."?

@user24723440: You're allowed to put an inline specifier on any function with internal linkage, but for functions with external linkage, the given restrictions apply.

It means that putting inline on a function with internal linkage does not add any additional restrictions to the the function and how or where it must be defined -- it needs to follow the same rules as any other function with internal linkage (ie, it must be defined exactly once somewhere in the compilation unit).

@user2357112:Then, if a function is an inline function but there is no inline definition of it in the current translation unit. For example,  extern inline int foo(){...} , For  foo(); , is it still possible for it to be inlined rather than being a call?

@Chris Dodd:Then, if a function is an inline function but there is no inline definition of it in the current translation unit. For example, extern inline int foo(){...} , For foo(); , is it still possible for it to be inlined rather than being a call?

Your example extern inline int foo(){...} is an inline function definition, so you can't have it and not have a definition.  A function declaration has ; instead of {...} after the ().

@Chris Dodd:No,  extern inline int foo(){...}  does not meet the requirements for an inline definition. It should belong to an external definition. foo  is an inline function, but the definition of the function is not an inline definition.
