# gcc denying inline request

Tags: c++, gcc, inline

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline int square(int n)
{
    return n * n;
}

int main(void)
{
    cout << square(2) << endl;
}
```

By compiling the code using gcc I found out that the compiler is still treating the square function as simple function rather than as inline.

(I checked out the assembly code and there I saw call to square function. That's how I knew it's not treating it as inline.)

Why is it denying my request to make the function inline even though its a simple function? 
If gcc is denying such a simple function inline then what's the use of inline keyword?

I can force inline the function; that's not the problem. I just want to know why gcc is declining my request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force gcc to inline a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381293/how-do-i-force-gcc-to-inline-a-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inline` is essentially ignored on modern mainstream compilers (it just enables [the usual exemption to the ODR for the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4193698/214671)). The optimizer will do his thing anyway, and it probably knows better than you or me (although there's usually some compiler-specific flag to force the inlining of a function).

Anyway, probably you are not seeing any inlining there because you compiled with optimizations disabled - a setting used often in debugging, where inlining and other optimizations makes impossible to match source lines to compiled code (and thus stepping through in a debugger). Enabling optimizations `-O3` on my machine (g++ 4.8.4) makes the function disappear completely - the result (`4`) is evaluated completely at compile time.

---

To sum it up: currently, the point of `inline` is to allow you to supply the function definition in multiple translation units without having linker errors for multiple definitions of a function.

This is useful because if you have a good candidate for inlining you want to put it into a header file (so that compiling each `.cpp` the compiler can see immediately its definition, and expand it inline right away - link time code generation is just a recent thing) but you want the linker to know that the extra non-`inline` copies that arise refer all to the same thing, and can be discarded safely (marking them as `static` would lead to unnecessary code duplication in each TU).

Answer (score 1):

You are not compiling with optimization enabled. Even with `-O1` your code compiles to the equivalent of

```
int main () {
    std::cout << 4;
}
```

Also, don't you worry about what should be inlined and what not, let the compiler do that for you. It is *way* better. (As always, unless you proof by measurement that the compiler was wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Compile with optimizations, e.g. `g++ -O3 ...`.