# How to simultaneously inline function and make it dynamic symbol in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, dynamic, inline

My project links with some external libraries (including some libc) and has a lot of it's own code. I want to override `memcpy` with my own implementation. In case of project's code I want to always-inline my `memcpy` while I also want all external libraries to use my `memcpy` too.

If I define my function as `inline void * memcpy(…)` then it won't be exported as dynamic symbol, but if I skipped the `inline` keyword, then I can't guarantee that compiler will try to inline my function wherever possible.

What is a proper way to incline a compiler to inline my function while having it as dynamic symbol for other external libraries?

I link my project statically with `-rdynamic` flag to expose symbols for override in other dynamic libraries.

Comment: No, if you specify `inline`, but not `static`, a global symbol has to be created for this function. It just _may_ be inlined _additionally_ when it is in the same translation unit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inline function linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193639/inline-function-linkage)

Comment: C or C++? Choose *one*.  Inline functions is one of the areas where it makes a difference.

Comment: @Ctx Maybe it's crucial, but the memcpy has `extern "C"` linkage. I checked with `nm` that memcpy is exported as Undefined symbol

Comment: @JohnBollinger it's defined in header (.h) which is included, compiled and linked depending on the including file. The resulting artifact is a single binary.

Comment: Irrelevant, @abyss.7.  You have tagged both [c] and [c++].  These are different languages with similar syntax and a shared lineage.  Their rules about inline functions are different.  **Choose *one***, and update the question's tags accordingly.