# Variable argument list with different types in MetaTrader5

Tags: variadic-functions, mql4, mql5, metatrader5

I have some mql5 code which I want to print debug messages if the `DEBUG` macro is set. I would like to use a different function (`DebugPrint` for that matter) for those debug messages. My first attempt was to create a regular function, but variable arguments don't seem to work. I then tried to use the precompiler to remove the `DebugPrint`-calls [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547007/4357595), however the compiler's pre-processor doesn't seem to understand the variable argument list either. This is the code I tried:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DebugPrint(...)
#else
#define DebugPrint(...) Print(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

My few cents on MQL4/5:

---

### Preprocessor directives:

while the revised *New*-**`MQL4.56789`** compiler has opened some new, more complex constructs for **`#define`** preprocessor directives syntax, I have almost always burnt my fingers when trying to use them in production code.

---

### Variadic arguments:

MQL4/5 is a strong-typed, compiled language and as such does not provide means for variadic functions. With some recent syntax aids, coming from ( OOP ) Class-based function ( method ) call-interface overrides and maybe using some advanced abstractions from so called function-**`template`**-s, there are chances to create some sort of syntax-support for your **`#define`**-dependent behaviour.

---

### Function Overloading,
**`template`**-s
and
`typename`-dependent actions:

Whereas these techniques have brought even more *"New"* compiler features into the MQL4/5 software domain, the additional levels of complexity do not justify the efforts, given the resulting principles are restricted from being usable in cases where their use is restricted from **`export`**, **`virtual`** or `#import` constructs.

---

### So how to make this work?

Well, for the sake of the rapid & iterative development needs, one may resort to an **"*almost*-variadic"**  `PrintFormat( DEBUG_MASK, ..., ..., ... );` using a context-full (known) matching set of attributes against a static, context-specific `#define`-ed **`DEBUG_MASK`**. Nested construction of `FormatString( MASK_A, par1, par2[, FormatString( MASK_B, par3, par4[, FormatString( ... )[, ... ] )[, ... ])` are left for one's own kind imagination.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could please help me out with this question stackoverflow.com/questions/60933737/converting-mql4-ea-to-mql5