# Visual Studio does not allow breakpoints in MVC views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

Sometimes Visual Studio does not allow me to set breakpoints in MVC views.  This has happened to me scores of times, but it doesn't happen for every view and I don't know why.

When you click on the left-hand bar to place a breakpoint, it places a white circle instead of the normal red circle.  The message when you hover over it is "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version."  It goes on to describe how to allow breakpoints to be hit, but that produces strange results and I don't want that anyways.

If the error is correct, then I want to run the original source code.  I don't know what's going on behind the scenes in VS; I try rebuilding and all that but it doesn't help.  I'm running in Debug mode in VS 2012.

[image: screenshot of trying to place a breakpoint in vs 2012 MVC razor view]

Comment: are you running in release and don't have it configured to generate the pdb files? You absolutely can, something else is at play here that is blocking it. There's a lot of variables that can cause this though.

Comment: I'm running in debug.  Is there any other relevant information I should include in my question?

Comment: there isn't a whole lot more you can add. like i said, so many variables could be at play. it could be copying dll from another projects output directory, could be that it's not generating pdb's, could be that it's pointing to other files than what you are expecting, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be caused by many things, but a few items to check which I've helped people with recently:

- First step: there must be a PDB file alongside the DLL to enable debugging. (see: [What is a PDB file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file)) Make sure you have the PDB in the executing directory.
- Clean to remove all the old DLLs from your bin folders.
- Ensure that your application is running a build of your current code (the same version you have in Visual Studio). Don't assume that it is just because you clicked 'build' or 'deploy'. If no changes were detected then things often don't happen. Check the build time of the assembly, or change something and rebuild to see the file size change.
- If you're running something web-related, make sure a browser isn't caching code, or IIS isn't holding a long running process.
- Kill any running Visual Studio Development Server instances (you can do this from task manager, or more simply from the system tray - they look like an IE logo and when you hover over them they'll tell you which port they run on).
- Restart IIS using `iisreset` from a command prompt.
- Check the settings for Debugging in Visual Studio (`Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols`) You want to automatically load symbols, and if you're linking other assemblies you need to reference their PDB files here.

Comment: See my comment below re: web.config to amend your list of things to check

Answer (score 2):

So I had this issue this morning and the fix for me was related to razor syntax.

I was setting a variable inside an if statement

```
@If (my condition)
{
  myVar1 = "blah blah blah"
  @myVar2 = 1 <== This line here was causing my razor to crap out on render
}
```

So all of the other things are good things however, improper razor syntax can also cause the breakpoint issue. In this case it was the @ symbol on myVar2 inside the code block... Just an FYI

Comment: While this question was for VS2012, I am currently on VS2015

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I've found to work around this problem is:

Set a breakpoint in the controller code that is right before the View is called.  Then, when that breakpoint is hit, step through (using F10) several times.  It will go through _ViewStart.cshtml and maybe another thing or two.  But soon it will get to the view.

Once you are in the view, then hitting F5 (continue) will take you to the breakpoint in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Fom the answer nothing worked for me to set a breakpoint in the javascript code.
I moved the javascript code inside  to file Scripts\myscript.js and replaced the script block to

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @kirk-broadhurst answer, (please amend if possible), double check your web.config, specifically the `compilation` flag under system.web.  Even if you are building for debug, if the `debug` attribute is set to false, you will run into issues debugging Razor.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure that "debug" is set and Voila ... debug is working again:-)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your Solution configuration set to Debug not on release.

Thanks