# VisualStudio Debugger can't hit breaking point

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have a universal apps project. It contains different portable windows runtime components for example for the business layer and the data layer. Now I have a really strange issue. Some of the methods are not debuggable. If I set a breakpoint on one of it it will turn white when I start the debugger. When I set the breakpoint where the method is called it just will skip the method for debugging but will execute the code.
I can make changes to the code and it will apply. All rebuilding, cleaning and rebooting didn't help.

If I activate the just my code option in the debugger option it will keep it red, will move it some lines down or top but will never hit it.

I tried it on different pc's deleted the obj and bin folders, repaired vs installation  ..

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? oO

EDIT: I noticed that altough I can set different breaking points and most of them are marked as active (red ball) none of them get hit. If that makes a difference: they are all in internal classes.

thanks
NPadrutt

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what is causing your problem but in the link below there is a few solutions. I hope you can find your solution. 
[Visual Studio does not allow breakpoints in MVC views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495698/visual-studio-does-not-allow-breakpoints-in-mvc-views)

Some reasons a breakpoint will not to be hit:

The executable and the code do not match. For example, you changed the code, but the executable was in use when you compiled, and was not actually updated.
The executable is running in Administrative mode, but Visual Studio is running as a regular user.
Breakpoints can be disabled, but still exist. Go to the breakpoints window and be sure the breakpoint is enabled.

When the breakpoints are white that is the indication that Visual Studio is unable to match up the place in the source file with the application it is being debugged. Typically this occurs for the following reasons

The source and executable are out of date. A full rebuild will often fix this
The PDB files for the executable cannot be located. Go to Debug -> Windows -> Modules and make sure the PDB is correctly loaded

Comment: thanks for your answer and your link. I tried the things suggested there, but couldn't find an answer. The modules are all loaded and breaking points are fine. Really strange is that other classes or are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that the type of the component was a windows runtime comonent. I guess this will be compiled to native code and is optimized so that it can't be debugged after that..
I changed it to Class Library and now it's fine..