# Why did my Visual Studio start acting this way? iisexpress cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2013

When I first created my project and ran it, I didn't get these messages:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

So what did I do to my VS config, or maybe my project properties that caused this issue?

Before this started happening, running the application took a minute or two, now I'm waiting more like 5 mins. Which is nuts, there is something wrong with my config somewhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937707/error-message-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file. Search your exception in the google next time, almost every time someone had your problem. This research cost me under 1 min. This will help you with future problems too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason you started getting the message

"'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file."  is because that DLL is now being loaded during execution, and wasn't being loaded previously.

The missing PDB file however is not part of your problem.  You can get rid of the warning message by obtaining this PDB file from Microsoft.  But I suggest you focus on what you did to make it start appearing (ie when you started loading System.Web.dll).  This might help explain why it takes longer to load.

Answer (score 1):

PDB (program database) files contain debug information that is used by Visual Studio.

I would first try cleaning your solution, rebuild it in debug mode, and see if that solves your issue. That should re-create your PDB's for you.

Also, If you go to Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols in Visual Studio and select Microsoft Symbol servers, it will try to download the correct PDB's for you. Then try rebuilding in debug mode.

Comment: Why did my VS start this process in the first place? It wasn't doing this before. And plus, why would I wand PDB for the frameworks DLLs? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: PDB files contain project debug information. They provide information when debugging (things like where breakpoints are, etc.). Take a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file

Even for .NET dlls, PDB files are created to keep track of debugging information. It's how Visual Studio and its compiler keep track of "state" essentially for debugging purposes.