# VS 2013 Express -- How to see line number of error

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, jit

For a beta release, I'd like to deploy my VS 2013 Express C# app with some debugging enabled. What do I need to enable to be able to see the line number that an error occurred on?

I noticed that VS Express doesn't support JIT. Does that mean I'm out of luck?

Thanks...

Comment: If you are doing a release build, did you include the [program database (.pdb) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file) when deploying? Regarding VS Express, the availability of JIT is a property of the environment in which the code is executed, not where it's built.