# vs2012 release build extra files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I used VS2012 to build a very small console app. After I build it in release mode, not release(active), it still generates debug file such as

- .pdb
- .vshost.exe
- .exe.config
- .vshost.exe.config
- .vshost.exe.manifest

Why are they there?
How can I make VS not to generate them?

Thanks,

Comment: do you know what .pdb file is used for.. what exe.config file is..? do some googling and check MSDN and understand they why and what in regards to what those different files are used for..

Comment: *Why* don't you want them generated? Besides, some of them are *not* debug files, they are part of your application, like `exe.config`, or the host exe that allows you to run your application by running F5 even in Release mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in release modes it is useful to have debugging.

For more information on pdb files and how to stop them see

[What is a PDB file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file)

Config files allow you to change variables in an executable without rebuilding code.

Manifests allow you to embed programs or use them as resources.

ALL OF THESE ARE USEFUL. Please don't turn them off.

Comment: Thanks Seth. Appreciate your help!