# Why is my Sitecore.Context.Language resetting in Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

Sitecore appears to be doing something freaky with the language variable in it's Context object. If I load a CMS page using the url `?sc_Lang=ru-RU` (get the Russian version of my site), by the time it get's to my MVC controller it's reset to the language back to `en`

```
public PartialViewResult Navigation()
{
    //en
    var language = Sitecore.Context.Language;
}
```

I know that sitecore does set this at some point because if I add a HTTP pipeline I can see `Sitecore.Context.Language` as `ru-RU`:

```
public class LanguageResolver
{
    public void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        //ru-RU
        var language = Sitecore.Context.Language;
    }
}
```

Registered:

```xml
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="namespace.LanguageResolver,RR.Web.Sc.Extensions" patch:source="Languages.config"/>
```

as recommended on the [sitecore blog post](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2010/11/overriding-sitecores-logic-to-determine-the-context-language.aspx)

I did some digging into the sitecore dlls and I noticed that `Sitcore.Context.Language` is basically a wrapper for `HttpContext.Current.Items["sc_Language"]`. When I inspect this I see the same results (i.e. in the pipeline it's `ru-RU` in the controller it's `en`)

So something somewhere is turning this `HttpContext` `Item` to `"en"`.

As an experiment I dropped a new variable into the `Items` collection. I can then see this again (in it's correct state) in Controller, so the Items collection is getting passed into the controller correctly.

I didn't originally develop this site but I can't see anywhere in the code base that changes this language variable.

Has anyone else experienced this? Anything I've missed? Anything I need to configure, check?

The sitecore docs (as usual) are pretty woeful on this subject.

---

To follow up on the comment from @jammykam:

I can see the lang cookie the Response `Set-Cookie: redrow#lang=ru-RU; path=/` and the languages are set up:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure something funky is not happening, can you try clearing your cookies (or check them and make sure `website#lang=ru-RU`). Have you added `ru-RU` to Sitecore? Does your local system support it?

Comment: @jammykam, added details above. I'm intrigued if anyone has view'd this in an MVC environment before? I'm guessing it's worked for someone, somewhere?

Comment: Can you move your language resolver before item resolver? Default order in Sitecore is: <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/> other procesors ... and after <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>

Comment: The language resolver isn't actually doing anything at the moment though, I'm just using it as an intercept to see what the language is set to further up the pipeline. @sitecoreclimber Now that said it might be interesting to move it around in the pipeline...mmm

Comment: Just check if is working and if yes I will move my comment like an answer

Comment: Moving the pipeline around hasn't really helped. As far as I can tell the language is correct in all the httpRequestBegin pipelines. I even overrode a few to make sure that the standard one's weren't changing this.

Comment: And just to be sure, the language that has been installed is `ru-RU` and not just `ru`? Did you add the language via the Sitecore Control Panel?

Comment: yes and yes @jammykam

Comment: I've given up, I'm implementing my own and storing it in the context items myself. I wanted a non-standard location for the language anyway.

Comment: You can open User Manager and set up languages that you prefer per users. It will work for Content Editor. However in you controller language is get from site context. Go to your site configuration and set language that you need .

Comment: Are you logged with a sitecore user at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

There are [a few places in code](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) where Language setter is used OOB in [Sitecore 10](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/100/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%20100/Release%20Notes):

[image]

Even though callees from `Sitecore.MVC` namespace on top of suspected list, I'd recommend to debug **Sitecore.Context.Language** setter by [restoring PDBs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file) [and loading them to debugger](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/Debugging-framework-internals-without-source-code) to get the actual culprit. You'll also see the mechanics/motivation behind the *language-switch logic*.

Even though `getter` might be optimized, you still could [disable optimizations to ease debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/making-an-image-easier-to-debug).

Comment: I haven't worked on sitecore for about 6 years so I can't really upvote or accept this answer as I don't know if it's helpful or not. So I'll have to see what other people think