# kofax export script project setup

Tags: kofax

For my first export script I took the KCEC example and the *APIRefExport.chm* documentation to create my project by replacing the example code with my own.

I would like to create a clean export script from scratch.

I created a new class library project and called it `EmptyExportScript` (placeholder). The target framework is *.Net 4*. The platform target is *x86* and the output path is `.....\Program Files (x86)\Kofax\CaptureSS\ServLib\Bin\`. When debugging I would like to start the administration module so I set this path `.......\Program Files (x86)\Kofax\CaptureSS\ServLib\Bin\`.

The option "Make assembly COM-Visible" is checked and I added the *Kofax.ReleaseLib.Interop.dll* to the references.

For the *KfxReleaseScript.cs* I added this code

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("KFXTS.EmptyExportScript.KfxReleaseScript")]
public class KfxReleaseScript
{
    public ReleaseData documentData;

    // public KfxReturnValue OpenScript()

    // public KfxReturnValue ReleaseDoc()

    // public KfxReturnValue CloseScript()
}
```

For the *KfxReleaseScriptSetup.cs* I added this code

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("KFXTS.EmptyExportScript.KfxReleaseScriptSetup")]
public class KfxReleaseScriptSetup
{
    public ReleaseSetupData setupData;

    // public KfxReturnValue OpenScript()

    // public KfxReturnValue CloseScript()

    // public KfxReturnValue RunUI()

    // public KfxReturnValue ActionEvent(KfxActionValue actionID, string data1, string data2)
}
```

Lastly I added a `Form` to the project when running the UI.

For registration I added a `EmptyExportScript.inf` with this content

```
[Scripts]
Empty Export

[Empty Export]
SetupModule=EmptyExportScript.dll
SetupProgID=KFXTS.EmptyExportScript.KfxReleaseScriptSetup
SetupVersion=10.2
ReleaseModule=EmptyExportScript.dll
ReleaseProgID=KFXTS.EmptyExportScript.KfxReleaseScript
ReleaseVersion=10.2
SupportsNonImageFiles=True
SupportsKofaxPDF=True
RemainLoaded=True
SupportsOriginalFileName=False
```

When building the project .dll and .inf file get placed into the kofax bin directory.

I recognized that other scripts have a .pdb and .dll.config file in there too.

How do I get them?

When trying to install the custom script, I can add it to the script installation manager but I can't install it. There is nothing to install so I think I'm missing the .pdb and .dll.config file.

Is anything else missing?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Kofax does not need a `pdb` file, but they are handy if you want to debug your connector and attach it to the release.exe process (learn more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file)).

I would not recommend changing the output path itself to `Capture\Bin`, but rather create a post-build event:

[image: post build event]

For example, the following line copies all required files to a separate folder under the `CaptureSS\Bin` folder:

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)*" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kofax\CaptureSS\ServLib\Bin\SmartCAP\kec\SmartCAP.KEC.Template\" /Y /S
```

Having a `dll.config` file is possible, but rare. I would rather recommend storing process-specific data in a custom storage string object of the respective batch class definition (which has the added benefit that you can just import/export the definition along with the batch class, and that you can display and have it changed it in setup form). Having said all that, back to your initial issue - the connector can't be installed.

### COM visibility

The assembly needs to be COM-visible, but you mentioned that it was. For the sake of completeness, here's what you will need to do. Note that the GUID must be unique (only relevant if you copied an existing solution):

[image: COM visible assembly]

If you're installing the connector on a different machine, you will need to register it first using regasm.exe - here's an example:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" SampleExport.dll /codebase /tlb:SampleExport.tlb
```

## ProgIds

Then, your .inf file needs to contain the precise ProgIDs:

```
[Scripts]
SampleExport

[SampleExport]
SetupModule=SampleExport.dll
SetupProgID=SampleExport.Setup
SetupVersion=11.0
ReleaseModule=SampleExport.dll
ReleaseProgID=SampleExport
ReleaseVersion=11.0
SupportsNonImageFiles=True
SupportsKofaxPDF=True
```

Both your `ReleaseScript.cs` and `ReleaseSetupScript.cs` files need the correct attribute, for example:

```
[ProgId("SampleExport")]
public class ReleaseScript
```

If that all still does not work, please provide us with the detailed error message (to be found at CaptureSV\Logs).

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the file format from **UTF-8** to **UTF-8 without BOM**.

This worked for me.