# C#/.Net 4. -- PDB in GAC w/ DLL, in order to step into/debug the source code for my DLL. WHY?

Tags: c#, .net, gac, pdb-files

**C#/.Net devs:** 
I've a DLL project. To debug I created a solution and with a Win Forms project with reference to DLL, included the project for the DLL.   Recently, I had to sign the DLL w/ strong name key so it could be installed in GAC on a Win Server, running SQL Server/SSIS and be called by SSIS packages.

I tested this by installing compiled DLL in GAC on dev machine.   What I now find is that I can't step into the DLL project from the Win Forms project unless my code with any changes are compiled and the resulting DLL AND the PDB are placed in the GAC and the new version of DLL is installed there, after uninstalling the prior version DLL.

It seems that all this effort is required simply to test/debug even a change to a single line of code.

No doubt I'm missing something. It can't that difficult.  I have learned some things from [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file) other [posts](https://www.wintellect.com/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know) but I haven't picked up on quite this issue. Or, maybe everyone simply accepts this as the way it is?  Any help or links to help explaining this and why it's necessary, or what I'm doing incorrectly are appreciated.

Just the fact that the solution and projects have to build/compile every time we run the process for test/debug purposes seems tedious.  Having to go out an interface with GAC for every little adjustment during debug/test additionally. . . I might to stop defending C#/.Net to co-workers.  But, I bet I missing something.  Help me out please.

Jim.

Comment: 1) The pdb symbol file can live in a symbol cache folder, or on symbol servers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/debugging-with-symbols 2) Symbols should be generated whenever you compile the source code so that they match the assemblies. 3) Sometimes a slightly mismatched symbol can still be used, but you should stick to 2).

Comment: @LexLi  You seem to know what you're talking about. Thanks for comment.  So it makes sense to have to move DLL to GAC, register it, and PDB. Just to debug? I don't even like fact I have to build every time I run for test/debug. I think I'm doing something wrong.