# Memory dump async Task analysis with MEX and "method" column

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, memory-dump

I am trying to analyze .NET memory dump and state of Task objects on heap. I am using fantastic WinDBg extension [MEX](https://github.com/REhints/WinDbg/tree/master/MEX). `!TaskTriage` shows all Tasks in very nice table. Some of them has value in method column but for most there is null like this:

```
000001fa33b4e658 | Task<System.Object>             |           <null> | TASK_STATE_WAITINGFORACTIVATION | <null>
```

I would like to know in which situations info about method is available and if I can do something in my code to have this information included.

Comment: Is the dump from a Debug or Release build?

Comment: It is from Release build. However method isn't <null> for all tasks

Comment: In a Release build the compiler can inline methods, which would result in there not being a mrthod name.

Comment: That would mean that almost all async methods I have in code has been inlined and few from 3rd party library weren't. I will study rules for inlining but looks unlikely to me. Can there be something different?

Comment: Yes, I think you're probably right there. Do you have the [.pdb files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file) available from the Release build?

Comment: I would speculate the tasks without a method are created with `TaskCompletionSource<T>` which are not bound to any async method.

Comment: @stuartd Yes I have pdb files loaded