# How to build a single .exe file, with static .NET runtime, from a C# WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022
C# WPF Project

I want to distribute a single .exe file, without requiring the target computer to install .NET 6.0 runtimes.

I can only find solutions for C/C++ code generation in the project's property window, but what I see in VS 2022 is totally different and there's no settings for static linking.

Comment: Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained).  Just beware the reality that you then become responsible for ensuring updates to the core components.

Answer (score 1):

**How to Deploy a single-file .NET 6 WPF app:**

- Right-click on the WPF application project in the **Solution Explorer** and select **Edit Project File**
- Add the following line to the `<PropertyGroup>` element in the `.csproj` file:

  ```
  <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
  ```
- Right-click on the project in the **Solution Explorer** and select **Publish**
- Set the **Deployment mode** to **Self-contained** under the **Target Runtime** settings
- Select win-* as the **Target runtime**
- Check the **Produce single file** option under **File publish options**
- Click on **Save** and then on **Publish**
- Copy the contents of the **Target location** to the target machine and run the app`

**.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
        <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract >true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**FolderProfile.pubxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
  -->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net6.0-windows\publish\win-x64\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I still got multiple output files
```
D3DCompiler_47_cor3.dll
PenImc_cor3.dll
PresentationNative_cor3.dll
vcruntime140_cor3.dll
wpfgfx_cor3.dll
[project_name].exe
[project_name].pdb
```

with the following configuration:

Comment: FolderProfile.pubxml
```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net6.0-windows\publish\win-x64\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: [Project].csproj
```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <IncludeAllContentFileForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentFileForSelfExtract>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: See my edit for an example of a working configuration and compare it to yours.

Comment: IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract is usually not a great idea; it extracts *all* DLLs to the filesystem which can be slow and take up more disk space.

IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract should be good enough to get those last DLLs included in the exe. See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview#including-native-libraries

Comment: @ReillyWood: That's a very good point. I replaced `IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract` with `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` in my answer. The rest is the same.

Comment: My publish generates two .pdb files, which looks like one for each project namespace. Are these files important? The executable runs fine without them.

Comment: No, they contain debugging information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899573/what-is-a-pdb-file