# Static code analysis: integrate into debug and release builds, or just one or the other?

Tags: code-analysis

As a best practice, do you run code analysis on both debug and release builds, or just one or the other?

Comment: What do you mean by debug and release builds? The code should be the same...

Comment: In .Net, if you use the Conditional output extensively, you could be producing slightly different builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually pick one and that one is the release build.  I guess it doesn't really matter but I tend to think that when gather information about what will run in production it is best to test *exactly* what will go to production (this goes for analysis, profiling, benchmarking, etc.).

Comment: So in your project's build config, do you define CODE_ANALYSIS in the release build?  Does that change the release build's output significantly or affect performance?

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason the two builds are different (and they really shouldn't be for static analysis purposes), you should ensure that your metrics are running against what's actually going out to production.

**Ideally,** you should have a CI server, and the commands that developers run to initiate such analysis **are no different** from what the CI server does.

Comment: Yep. The idea is to integrate the code analysis into the CI environment.

Answer (score 1):

Static Code Analysis will show the same results regardless of your build type.

Debug/Release only changes the resulting assembly and the inclusion or exclusion of debugging information at runtime.

Comment: right. and I guess you wouldn't care about the analysis of debug only code. makes sense.

Comment: This isn't completely true, a debug build will not be optimized by the compiler and may emit IL that will not be in a optimized release build.

Comment: @Andrew - True, I guess depending on how/where in the process the tool evaluates there could be some inlining and other optimizations that work in to release only builds.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have separate ‘debug’ and ‘release’ builds (see [Separate ‘debug’ and ‘release’ builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420343)).

Answer (score 0):

The LLVM folks actually recommend analyzing the DEBUG configuraion:

> **ALWAYS analyze a project in its "debug" configuration**
>
> Most projects can be built in a "debug" mode that enables assertions.
>   Assertions are picked up by the static analyzer to prune infeasible
>   paths, which in some cases can greatly reduce the number of false
>   positives (bogus error reports) emitted by the tool.

In addition, debug builds tend to be faster (no need for optimization), and in the CI world faster is always better (all else being equal).