# WP8 C++ Runtime Component: Debug vs Release

Tags: c, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I make some C-style functions in WP8 C++ runtime component. Every function take ponters for const input and output arrays. Debug version work great, but in Release some functions works wrong. The magic consist in simple thing: this functions have the same interface and works with pointers in the same way, but some functions work correct and other functions work wrong.

Which are standart problem exists with switching from Debug to Release in WP8 SDK Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 1):

The problems are the same as any other C/C++ Debug/Release build configuration - the exact issues will depend on your Debug/Release settings and what your code does.

Typically:

- the optimizer will move code and data around and/or remove code.
- Release code will also typically run faster due to the optimizer, so you will notice changes due to race-conditions.

You will need to get used to debugging in Release configuration on a real device. Getting the same code to run on the Emulator reliably will also help you with some race conditions too (as the x86 Emulator is faster than the ARM devices).

See "[Release /Debug hell, with V-studio C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167885/release-debug-hell-with-v-studio-c-project?rq=1)", "[Separate 'debug' and 'release' builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420343/separate-debug-and-release-builds?lq=1)".