# Node.js: should I keep `assert()`s in production code?

Tags: node.js, assert, assertions

A *methodological* question:

I'm implementing an API interface to some services, using node.js, mongodb and express.js.

On many (almost all) sites I see code like this:

```
method(function(err, data) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
});
```

The question is: should I keep `assert` statements in my code at production time (at least for 'low significance' errors)? Or, are these just for *testing* code, and I should better handle all errors each time?

Comment: I created a github issue to ask about the intention of the assert package. https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3266

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitively should not keep them in the *production* environment.

If you google a bit, there are a plethora of alternative approaches to strip out them.

Personally, I'd use the `null object` pattern by implementing two wrappers in a separate file: the former maps its method directly to the one exported by the module `assert`, the latter offers empty functions and nothing more.

Thus, at runtime, you can plug in the right one by relying on some global variable previously correctly set, like `process.env.mode`. Within your files, you'll have only to import the above mentioned module and use it instead of using directly `assert`.

This way, all around your code you'll never see error-prone stuff like `myAssert && myAssert(cond)`, instead you'll have ever a cleaner and safer `myAssert(cond)` statement.

It follows a brief example:

```
// myassert.js
var assert = require('assert');
if('production' === process.env.mode) {
    var nil = function() { };
    module.exports = {
        equal = nil;
        notEqual = nil;
        // all the other functions
    };
} else {
    // a wrapper like that one helps in not polluting the exported object
    module.exports = {
        equal = function(actual, expected, message) {
            assert.equal(actual, expected, message);
        },
        notEqual = function(actual, expected, message) {
            assert.notEqual(actual, expected, message);
        },
        // all the other functions
    }
}


// another_file.js
var assert = require('path_to_myassert/myassert');
// ... your code
assert(true, false);
// ... go on
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why one should not keep them in the production environment?

Comment: @SanghyunLee Expressions you use within the assert can be complex and usually you don't want to spend cpu cycle for things you don't want in production.

Comment: regarding the latter, you mean one could introduce a bug using `assert`, right?

Comment: @SanghyunLee A bug? No. Why should one introduce a bug with an assert? Usually the goal is the opposite one!!

Comment: ahh, okay I misunderstood. So only to reduce the cpu cycles.

Comment: If you're concerned about reducing cpu cycles in node.js, you're really playing the wrong game...

Comment: Re *" the null object pattern"* - I like this idea, but it doesn't seem sufficient, because the *expensive* part of assertion is *evaluating the expression*. That evaluation will happen, even if you pass it to a method that does nothing with it. Need to strip the entire assertion statement out - unless you limit assertions to calculations that are cheap. OTOH, expensive assertions are rare enough that maybe you live with `if (DEBUG) assert(...)` for those.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes!** asserts are good in production code.

1. Asserts allow a developer to document assumptions that the code makes, making code easier to read and maintain.
2. It is better for an assert to fail in production than allow the undefined behaviour that the assert was protecting. When an assert fails you can more easily see the problem and fix it.
3. Knowing your code is working within assumptions is far more valuable than a small performance gain.

I know opinions differ here. I have offered a 'Yes' answer because I am interested to see how people vote.

Answer (score -2):

probably no

ref: [When should assertions stay in production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732/when-should-assertions-stay-in-production-code)

Mostly in my code i put error handling function in a separate file , and use same error method everywhere, it mostly depends on logic anyways

like ppl generally forget this

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

and err==null doesn't hurts , it checks both null and undefined

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion when most of the answers of the link you referred to say yes?